# Export DataTable to Excel with Open Xml SDK in c#

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

My program have ability to export some data and DataTable to Excel file (template)
In the template I insert the data to some placeholders. It's works very good, but I need to insert a DataTable too...
My sample code:

```
using (Stream OutStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    // read teamplate
    using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(templatePath))
        fileStream.CopyTo(OutStream);

    // exporting
    Exporting(OutStream);
         
    // to start
    OutStream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            
    // out
    using (var resultFile = File.Create(resultPath))
        OutStream.CopyTo(resultFile);
```

Next method to exporting

```
private void Exporting(Stream template)
{
    using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(template, true, new OpenSettings                          { AutoSave = true }))
    {
        // Replace shared strings
        SharedStringTablePart sharedStringsPart = workbook.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart;
        IEnumerable<Text> sharedStringTextElements = sharedStringsPart.SharedStringTable.Descendants<Text>();
           
        DoReplace(sharedStringTextElements);
        // Replace inline strings
        IEnumerable<WorksheetPart> worksheetParts = workbook.GetPartsOfType<WorksheetPart>();
          
        foreach (var worksheet in worksheetParts)
        {
            DoReplace(worksheet.Worksheet.Descendants<Text>());
        }

        int z = 40;
        foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in ExcelWorkXLSX.ToOut.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < row.ItemArray.Count(); i++)
            { 
                ExcelWorkXLSX.InsertText(workbook, row.ItemArray.ElementAt(i).ToString(), getColumnName(i), Convert.ToUInt32(z)); }
                z++;
            }
        } 
        
    }
}
```

But this fragment to output DataTable slooooooooooooooooooooooowwwwwww...

How can I export DataTable to Excel fast and truly?

Comment: Do you need to use the open xml sdk?

Comment: Hmm... No, but open xml sdk fast read/write excel files. In my program i reading xlsx files, grabbing data to datagridview (using DataTable), recheck data. Firstly i used interop, but it need excel and very slow. My problem is only export. But, I would't want to rewrite a lot of code at this moment :)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I wrote this quick example. It works for me. I only tested it with one dataset with one table inside, but I guess that may be enough for you.

Take into consideration that I treated all cells as String (not even SharedStrings). If you want to use SharedStrings you might need to tweak my sample a bit.

*Edit: To make this work it is necessary to add WindowsBase and DocumentFormat.OpenXml references to project.*

Enjoy,

```
private void ExportDataSet(DataSet ds, string destination)
        {
            using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(destination, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
                var workbookPart = workbook.AddWorkbookPart();

                workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook();

                workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets();

                foreach (System.Data.DataTable table in ds.Tables) {

                    var sheetPart = workbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                    var sheetData = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData();
                    sheetPart.Worksheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet(sheetData);

                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets sheets = workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets>();
                    string relationshipId = workbook.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(sheetPart);

                    uint sheetId = 1;
                    if (sheets.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Count() > 0)
                    {
                        sheetId =
                            sheets.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
                    }

                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet sheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = table.TableName };
                    sheets.Append(sheet);

                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row headerRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();

                    List<String> columns = new List<string>();
                    foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in table.Columns) {
                        columns.Add(column.ColumnName);

                        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                        cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                        cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(column.ColumnName);
                        headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
                    }


                    sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

                    foreach (System.Data.DataRow dsrow in table.Rows)
                    {
                        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row newRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();
                        foreach (String col in columns)
                        {
                            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                            cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                            cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(dsrow[col].ToString()); //
                            newRow.AppendChild(cell);
                        }

                        sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think `workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new...` and `workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new` should be moved outside the foreach loop.  Otherwise, each iteration of the loop replaces the worksheets, causing the excel file to contain only the final `DataTable`.

Comment: @Brian , thanks for pointing that out. It originally worked because I only tested with one table. I just fixed it, does it look ok now?

Comment: Yeah, it looks fine.  As an aside that doesn't matter much, calling `.Max(s=>s.SheetId.Value)` is cleaner than calling `.Select(s=>s.SheetId.Value).Max()` . Similarly, you don't need a `List<String> columns` since `DataRow` has a `DataColumn` indexer; the second `foreach` can iterate over `table.Columns` as well.

Comment: oh well, this is for educational purposes only I guess :)  thanks

Comment: @eburgos this code is amazing ..Can we export an image form our local drive and show it in excel cell .i need it badly

Comment: @RahulChowdhury thanks. Yes you can, it is a bit different though because an image is an external resource that should be embedded in your excel file and included from within your worksheet. I see you wrote this comment 2 days ago (sorry for the late response), do you still need it?

Comment: I couldn't find references for `SpreadsheetDocument` and `WorksheetPart` in `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` reference. Would you please specify the references too?

Comment: I figured it out myself. To make this work it is necessary to add `WindowsBase` and `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` references to project. Also `SpreadsheetDocument` and `WorksheetPart` are in `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging` namespace

Comment: ah sorry I just noticed this comment now. I will add this to the answer. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: Ten years later and out of the dozens of examples I've seen this is the only one that works. Not even Microsoft's examples show how to do this. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Haha, It is my pleasure. Glad it helped you!

Answer (score 18):

eburgos, I've modified your code slightly because when you have multiple datatables in your dataset it was just overwriting them in the spreadsheet so you were only left with one sheet in the workbook. I basically just moved the part where the workbook is created out of the loop. Here is the updated code.

```
private void ExportDSToExcel(DataSet ds, string destination)
{
    using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(destination, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
    {
        var workbookPart = workbook.AddWorkbookPart();
        workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook();
        workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets();

        uint sheetId = 1;

        foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
        {
            var sheetPart = workbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            var sheetData = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData();
            sheetPart.Worksheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet(sheetData);                

            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets sheets = workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets>();
            string relationshipId = workbook.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(sheetPart);

            if (sheets.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Count() > 0)
            {
                sheetId =
                    sheets.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
            }

            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet sheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = table.TableName };
            sheets.Append(sheet);

            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row headerRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();

            List<String> columns = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                columns.Add(column.ColumnName);

                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(column.ColumnName);
                headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
            }

            sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

            foreach (DataRow dsrow in table.Rows)
            {
                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row newRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();
                foreach (String col in columns)
                {
                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                    cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                    cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(dsrow[col].ToString()); //
                    newRow.AppendChild(cell);
                }

                sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just saw Brian's comment and I did the same on mine.

Comment: could u include a version which return bytes and also a version whch takes just a datatable and not a dataset

Answer (score 9):

I also wrote a C#/VB.Net "Export to Excel" library, which uses OpenXML and (more importantly) also uses OpenXmlWriter, so you won't run out of memory when writing large files.

Full source code, and a demo, can be downloaded as a NuGet package:

[Export to Excel](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Easy.ExportToExcel/1.0.6)

It's dead easy to use.
Just pass it the filename you want to write to, and a `DataTable`, `DataSet` or `List<>`.

```
CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(myDataSet, "MyFilename.xlsx");
```

And if you're calling it from an ASP.Net application, pass it the `HttpResponse` to write the file out to.

```
CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(myDataSet, "MyFilename.xlsx", Response);
```

Comment: Sorry...!  It's alive and kicking again now.

Comment: @MikeGledhill any workaround doing it asynchronously? I get out of memory exception when trying to write to a huge file, I've read all the related posts pretty much seems like it is limited to available memory?

Comment: @Afr0: This shouldn't be the case.  My libraries use OpenXmlWriter which write out the data as it's going along, rather than attempting to build up the entire Excel file in memory first.  If possible, drop me an email via my website, and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: may be there is something how the codebase I have got is written not quite sure.

Comment: Export Link broken.

Comment: This project link is broken.

Comment: Sorry guys...   I moved my library to NuGet.   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Easy.ExportToExcel/1.0.6

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my own export to Excel writer because nothing else quite met my needs.  It is fast and allows for substantial formatting of the cells.  You can review it at

https://openxmlexporttoexcel.codeplex.com/

I hope it helps.

Comment: This site can’t be reached

Answer (score 0):

You could try taking a look at this libary. I've used it for one of my projects and found it very easy to work with, reliable and fast (I only used it for exporting data).

http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks! This It's an idea! I will try it only for export.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at my library [here](https://openxmlpackaging.codeplex.com). Under the documentation section, you will find how to import a data table.

You just have to write

```
using (var doc = new SpreadsheetDocument(@"C:\OpenXmlPackaging.xlsx")) {
    Worksheet sheet1 = doc.Worksheets.Add("My Sheet");
    sheet1.ImportDataTable(ds.Tables[0], "A1", true);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I tried accepted answer and got message saying generated excel file is corrupted when trying to open. I was able to fix it by doing few modifications like adding below line end of the code.

`workbookPart.Workbook.Save();`

I have posted full code @ [Export DataTable to Excel with Open XML in c#](http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2015/11/export-datatable-to-excel-with-open-xml.html)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add this answer because I used the primary answer from this question as my basis for exporting from a datatable to Excel using OpenXML but then transitioned to OpenXMLWriter when I found it to be much faster than the above method.

You can find the full details in my answer in the link below. My code is in VB.NET though, so you'll have to convert it.

[How to export DataTable to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207869/how-to-export-datatable-to-excel/61644625#61644625)