# how to export from database to excel file using mvc3 c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, excel, razor, openxml, oledbconnection

I'm working on 'mvc3 Razor' application under 'IIS7', I want the generate an excel file (.xls or .xlsx) which get the data from a database  with a specific colors and format and with a good performance. How can i do this?

Comment: There's a lot of info here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the libraries which allow you to create and manipulate Excel files, like [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) (open source) or [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/) (commercial). I have a positive experience with the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811143/export-datatable-to-excel-with-open-xml-sdk-in-c-sharp) . You can probably adjust it to your needs. That one generates an Excel file from a DataSet. Perhaps you could fill that DataSet with your database and then call that method.

Enjoy,

Comment: The performance of openxml is n't very good it is too slow ,so i'm looking for using oleDb
Thanks alot