# Any way of converting datareader/dataset/lists to XLS formatted string and load to memory stream?

Tags: c#, ftp, xls, memorystream

I need to get data from the database and send it to the FTP server in XLS format.
I have done the same for XML using memory stream. But, I am not sure how to format and load XLS to memory stream.
Any idea or approach? Sample code always helps.

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood your question. Read file to stream is standard for all files.

```
 new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(inputFilename))
```

Comment: It's good for saving XLS locally, but I still don't get how to load the XLS formatted data to memory stream directly. Any idea?

Comment: Look at the code link above (http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/source/browse/trunk/src/ExcelLibrary/Office/Excel/SpreadSheet/Workbook.cs). I do see "public void Save(Stream stream)"

Comment: Yes, but that means it's expecting stream as a parameter and not that it converts it to stream.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this answer, which uses the Excel OpenXML format. The fastest way to get an Excel without any external library.

[Export DataTable to Excel with Open Xml SDK in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811143/export-datatable-to-excel-with-open-xml-sdk-in-c-sharp)

Comment: It's good for saving XLS locally, but I still don't get how to load the XLS formatted data to memory stream. Any idea?