# Horizontally repeat data in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

my current `GridView_RowDataBound` displays data like :

```
A B C D E
```

i would like to display it like :

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

is there an easy way about this?

im not sure if this is possible with `Gridview`, i dont have any code in my .cs end of the `GridView_RowDataBound`.

currently the data is being repeated vertically on the excel export, i would like it to be horizontal

thnx

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel11" runat="server">
                        <span style="background-color: #">
                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView4" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EnableModelValidation="True" 
                            onrowdatabound="GridView4_RowDataBound" ShowHeader="False" Visible="false"  
                            Width="700px">
                            <Columns>


                                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Test">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Test") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" BackColor="Fuchsia" 
                                            Text='<%# Bind("Test") %>'></asp:Label>

                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>





                                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Test2">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Test2") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" BackColor="Fuchsia" 
                                            Text='<%# Bind("Test2") %>'></asp:Label>

                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                            </Columns>

                            <EmptyDataRowStyle Height="6px" />
                            <FooterStyle Height="4px" />
                            <HeaderStyle Font-Size="X-Small" Height="10px" />
                            <RowStyle Font-Size="X-Small" Height="6px" HorizontalAlign="Left" 
                                VerticalAlign="Top" />
                        </asp:GridView>

                    </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: `GridView` repeats data vertically by default, so i don't understand the question.

Comment: perhaps the op means only one row but with multiple columns which (s)he wants to transpose?

Comment: @TimSchmelter sorry i would like it repeated horizontally. :)

Comment: try to use listview/repeater

Comment: @user2910569: You can use a `DataList` which has a `RepeatDirection` property.

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh im fairly new to asp... any chance you could show me how the listview code would look?

Comment: @TimSchmelter will that effect my excel export in anyway? thnx

Comment: yes, it will affect your excel export as ListView need layout defination but user. it don't write everything in table as GridView does

Comment: @user2910569: i assume you're exporting html, so no, a `DataList` will also be rendered as table. But i would suggest to create real excel files anyway. For example by using the free epplus dll.

Comment: @TimSchmelter i will be exporting to ms excel

Comment: @user2910569: yes, probably by using `RenderControl` on the `GridView`/`DataList`. That works as excel understands html but you're not creating real excel files. That's why i've mentioned EPPlus. This can render real xlsx-excel files which can be opened with MS-Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well with GridView you can't do it.. have a look at the details below. What you want is a FlowLayout that is not supported in GridView.

[image]

If you are more concerned about export in excel. i would suggest to use OpenOfficeXML to export data to xls from DataTables as mentioned in the articles below:

http://openxmldeveloper.org/discussions/development_tools/f/35/t/6033.aspx

[Export DataTable to Excel with Open Xml SDK in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811143/export-datatable-to-excel-with-open-xml-sdk-in-c-sharp)

Comment: will the flow layout  datalist effect my excel export?

Comment: check edited answer for the export functionality.