# Export to Excel using OpenXML - Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml

I am using **OpenXML** for exporting data to Excel (`.xlsx`)
I am getting following error when I am trying to write Data having **29** columns and **62397** rows

[image]

However I have noiced that an xlsx file is created and all the rows have been written into it.

Please let me know if anything is missing.

The code is as follows

```
private static void ExporttoExcel(DataSet ds, SpreadsheetDocument sheet)
{
    try
    {           
        sheet.AddWorkbookPart();
        sheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.sheet.Workbook();

        sheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Append(new BookViews(new WorkbookView()));

        WorkbookStylesPart workbookStylesPart = sheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>("rIdStyles");
        Stylesheet stylesheet = new Stylesheet();
        workbookStylesPart.Stylesheet = stylesheet;


        int worksheetNumber = 1;
        foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
        {

            string workSheetID = "sheet" + worksheetNumber.ToString();
            string worksheetName = dt.TableName;

            WorksheetPart newWorksheetPart = sheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            newWorksheetPart.Worksheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.sheet.Worksheet();


            newWorksheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.sheet.SheetData());


            WriteDataTableToExcelWorksheet(dt, newWorksheetPart);
            newWorksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

            if (worksheetNumber == 1)
                sheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.sheet.Sheets());

            sheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.sheet.Sheets>().AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.sheet.Sheet()
            {
                Id = sheet.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(newWorksheetPart),
                SheetId = (int)worksheetNumber,
                Name = dt.TableName
            });

            worksheetNumber++;
        }

        sheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        sheet.Dispose();
    }
}

private static void WriteDTToExcel(DataTable dt, WorksheetPart worksheet)
{
    var worksheet = worksheet.Worksheet;
    var sheetData = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

    string cellValue = "";

    int numberOfColumns = dt.Columns.Count;
    bool[] IsNumericColumn = new bool[numberOfColumns];

    string[] excelColumnNames = new string[numberOfColumns];
    for (int n = 0; n < numberOfColumns; n++)
        excelColumnNames[n] = GetExcelColumnName(n);


    int rowIndex = 1;

    var headerRow = new Row { RowIndex = rowIndex };  // add a row at the top of sheet
    sheetData.Append(headerRow);

    for (int colInx = 0; colInx < numberOfColumns; colInx++)
    {
        DataColumn col = dt.Columns[colInx];
        AppendTextCell(excelColumnNames[colInx] + "1", col.ColumnName, headerRow);
        IsNumericColumn[colInx] = (col.DataType.FullName == "System.Decimal") || (col.DataType.FullName == "System.Int32");
    }

    double cellNumericValue = 0;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {

        ++rowIndex;
        var newExcelRow = new Row { RowIndex = rowIndex };  // add a row at the top of sheet
        sheetData.Append(newExcelRow);

        for (int colInx = 0; colInx < numberOfColumns; colInx++)
        {
            cellValue = dr.ItemArray[colInx].ToString();


            if (IsNumericColumn[colInx])
            {                   
                cellNumericValue = 0;
                if (double.TryParse(cellValue, out cellNumericValue))
                {
                    cellValue = cellNumericValue.ToString();
                    AppendNumericCell(excelColumnNames[colInx] + rowIndex.ToString(), cellValue, newExcelRow);
                }
            }
            else
            {                   
                AppendTextCell(excelColumnNames[colInx] + rowIndex.ToString(), cellValue, newExcelRow);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void AppendTextCell(string cellReference, string value, Row excelRow)
{       
    Cell cell = new Cell() { CellReference = cellReference, DataType = CellValues.String };
    CellValue cellValue = new CellValue();
    cellValue.Text = value;
    cell.Append(cellValue);
    excelRow.Append(cell);
}

private static void AppendNumericCell(string cellReference, string value, Row row)
{       
    Cell cell = new Cell() { CellReference = cellReference };
    CellValue cellValue = new CellValue();
    cellValue.Text = value;
    cell.Append(cellValue);
    row.Append(cell);
}

private static string GetExcelColumnName(int columnIndex)
{

    if (columnIndex < 26)
        return ((char)('A' + columnIndex)).ToString();

    char firstChar = (char)('A' + (columnIndex / 26) - 1);
    char secondChar = (char)('A' + (columnIndex % 26));

    return string.Format("{0}{1}", firstChar, secondChar);
}
```

Exception is thrown while executing following line of `ExporttoExcel` method

```
spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
```

Comment: Usually we get this exception when there is not enough space on the disk where you are storing the file. Have you checked about that?

Comment: I have plenty of space. Thank you.

Comment: My answer [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32690851/export-big-amount-of-data-from-xlsx-outofmemoryexception/32787219#32787219) might help you.

Comment: @captainsac I would suggest that you switch to [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus). It's actively supported, open source,very popular with the community, doesn't require additional downloads and can be installed from Nuget directly. There are *dozens* of related questions in SO

Comment: @petelids now *that's* a great trick! I have some 500K row Excel files myself! Can you help [with this similar question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41014891/export-to-excel-with-large-memory-stream-using-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment69239013_41014891)

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos - I'll take a look

Comment: The call stack you give indicates the error doesn't happen directly in your code, but is caused by ASP.NET view state serialization. You probably have put an object in a page, directly or indirectly (in a control, etc.) that ASP.NET tries to serialize that result in a too big string. If you don't use viewstate, you can try to desactivate it, at least to check how it's related : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableviewstate.aspx

Comment: I agree with Simon, run DebugDiag in OOM mode and reproduce the error then !Analyze the results. Report back to us the results and your findings.

Comment: Agree with Simon. Show the code where the ExporttoExcel() is called from.

Comment: I am not that well versed but you should take a look at this <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811143/export-datatable-to-excel-with-open-xml-sdk-in-c-sharp">article</a>

Comment: hey @captainsac did you find any work around for this?