# Specify Encoding Format when Export DataTable to Excel with Open Xml SDK in c#

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am just trying to export datatable as excel using open xml. Referred the below approach,

[Export DataTable to Excel with Open Xml SDK in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811143/export-datatable-to-excel-with-open-xml-sdk-in-c-sharp)

But I couldn't specify the encoding format of the excel created. I want to save or create the excecl with UTF-Encoding-8 format.

Can some one help on how could the formatting specificed using Open XML

Answer (score 2):

To save an Excel file with UTF-Encoding-8 Format you need to specify the encoding format under *Tools* -> *Web Options* -> *Encoding* while saving the excel file.

With OpenXML you need to create a new `WebPublishing` and add it to `Workbook`.

```
WebPublishing webPublishing1 = new WebPublishing(){ AllowPng = true, TargetScreenSize = TargetScreenSizeValues.Sz1024x768, CodePage = (UInt32Value)65001U };
workbook1.Append(webPublishing1);
//Where workbook1 is WorkbookPart.Workbook
```