# OpenXml SDK excel accented French Chars (éèçà)

Tags: c#, excel, openxml-sdk

I'm writing code to create excel files but i've trouble for french chars éèçà°.
they appears like a "�".
I've try to put a different font "Arial", "Calibri" but no change they still apearse as a black losange with interrogation pont in their.

if you have a solution i'm listening to you
Thanks in advance.
Demn

Comment: You need to set the correct Encoding(UTF-8) for your File, which contains these chars

Comment: Use the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44393927/specify-encoding-format-when-export-datatable-to-excel-with-open-xml-sdk-in-c-sh

Comment: thanks i was focus on the creation of the excel and forget to look at the file reader... sorry for your time spending. thanks all