# Export DataTable to Excel

Tags: c#, excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to export DataTable to Excel in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207869/how-to-export-datatable-to-excel-in-c-sharp)

I have TemplateExcel included in my project, and I want to Export my datatable to Excel, I want to copy and save this template with data everywhere I want to save it, how can I do it??

Comment: So you have a DataTable, and you want to export it to an Excel worksheet?

Comment: What type of DB? If it's SQL Server why not just use DTS http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917688.aspx or whatever the new one's called?

Comment: We need more detail to help you out!

Comment: @Liam I am assuming is is a `System.Data.DataTable` object

Comment: Yes, but if he just wants to export from a DB he could bypass the DataTable. Might not fit the solution, need more info.

Comment: Good point, didn't think of that

Comment: If you simply want to export data to make it viewable in excel surely you can just do it as a CSV?

Comment: hmmm I have do it but Sometimes works perfect and sometimes not O.0 and I don't know reason :/, I can't copy and paste my code here because limit of characters

Answer (score 7):

You can do it through Excel Interop like this:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Excel.Application application = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Add();
            Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Sheets[1];

            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            DataColumn column = new DataColumn("My Datacolumn");

            dataTable.Columns.Add(column);
            dataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {"Foobar"});

            var columns = dataTable.Columns.Count;
            var rows = dataTable.Rows.Count;

            Excel.Range range = worksheet.Range["A1", String.Format("{0}{1}", GetExcelColumnName(columns), rows)];

            object[,] data = new object[rows,columns];

            for (int rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < rows; rowNumber++)
            {
                for (int columnNumber = 0; columnNumber < columns; columnNumber++)
                {
                    data[rowNumber, columnNumber] = dataTable.Rows[rowNumber][columnNumber].ToString();
                }
            }

            range.Value = data;

            workbook.SaveAs(@"C:\test\whatever123.xlsx");
            workbook.Close();

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(application);
        }

        private static string GetExcelColumnName(int columnNumber)
        {
            int dividend = columnNumber;
            string columnName = String.Empty;
            int modulo;

            while (dividend > 0)
            {
                modulo = (dividend - 1) % 26;
                columnName = Convert.ToChar(65 + modulo).ToString() + columnName;
                dividend = (int)((dividend - modulo) / 26);
            }

            return columnName;
        }
    }
}
```

All I am doing here is creating a `System.Data.DataTable` object, filling it with some data and then exporting it to Excel. This needs cleaned up, error handling added, refactored etc but the basis is there.

Credit to [Graham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1826/graham) for the [GetExcelColumnName](https://stackoverflow.com/a/182924/969613) method.

Answer (score 0):

1 You can use this article - based on `RenderControl` , but you work on your binded Grid

Link : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/344604/Export-to-EXCEL-from-Datatable-in-Csharp-Net

2 You can base you developement on Table

Link : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/406704/Export-DataTable-to-Excel-with-Formatting-in-Cshar

Comment: hmm..workbook.SaveAs(@"C:\test\whatever123.xlsx");
 the method SaveAs can't have only one argument :/

Comment: thanks guys, the problem is sloved :)

Comment: Thank you Aghilas, I have another Question if you can help me, I'm getting path this way System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath.Replace(@"bin\Debug", "\\") + "something\\myFile.xls", when I install program the real path is Program Files (x86), but the way how i have call path returns Program Files without "(x86)" and i get error "Path not found" have you any idea how to get right path?