# Export Datatable to Excel and send it via email without saving the Excel first

Tags: c#, excel, email, datatable, office-interop

I need to export some information (in a .net datatable form) to excel and then send that information via email. I found this here [How to export DataTable to Excel in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207869/how-to-export-datatable-to-excel-in-c-sharp), works great but one of the requirements is not to save the Excel, kind of send the stream not the file itself, any Ideas? because all the examples that I found, all of them, save the Excel file first.

Comment: [`System.Net.Mail.Attachment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sdktyws(v=vs.110).aspx) has a constructor with an `IO.Stream`.

Comment: My problem is not the mail part, is how I create the excel without saving it, create a method to create the excel and return an stream, but don't know how to create an Excel stream with the Office.Interop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but i think that `Office.Interop` cannot do that.

Why don't you use [`EPPlus`](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) to load the excel from the `DataTable`. It has a `LoadFromDataTable` method and a `Stream` property:

```
using (var package = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
{
    var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheetname");
    sheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(tblData, true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Medium6);
    var excelAttachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(package.Stream, "Excelname");
    // ...
}
```

(note that this code is not tested)

Comment: Well, I was trying not to use another library (following orders) but I will give a shot to [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) and then try to convince the upper level management

Comment: well I ended using EPPlus, thanks @TimSchmelter for the advice, EPPlus has a lot of options for saving or whatever you want to do with the excel file, I used the package.GetAsByteArray(), thanks again