# Export Table from SQL Server to Excel 2007 using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, excel

my table in sql looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE InjuryScenario
(
InjuryScenario_id int identity(1,1),
InjuryDay int,
InjuryMonth int,
InjuryYear int,
InjuryDesc varchar(80),
InjuryComments varchar(50),
AlmostInjury int,
InjuryInSchool varchar(20),
ProductInjury varchar(20),
Cause_id int,
CauseType_id int,
CauseChar_id int,
Place_id int,
PlaceType_id int,
InjuryDate_id int,
Username varchar(50),
TimeStamp datetime default (getdate()),
constraint pk_InjuryScenario_id primary key (InjuryScenario_id),
constraint fk_Cause_InjuryScenario foreign key(Cause_id) references Cause(Cause_id) on delete cascade,
constraint fk_CauseType_InjuryScenario foreign key(CauseType_id) references CauseType(CauseType_id) on delete no action,
constraint fk_CauseChar_InjuryScenario foreign key(CauseChar_id) references CauseChar(CauseChar_id) on delete no action,
constraint fk_Place_InjuryScenario foreign key(Place_id) references Place(Place_id) on delete cascade,
constraint fk_PlaceType_InjuryScenario foreign key(PlaceType_id) references PlaceType(PlaceType_id) on delete no action,
constraint fk_InjuryDate_InjuryScenario foreign key(InjuryDate_id) references InjuryDate(InjuryDate_id) on delete cascade, 
constraint fk_Users_InjuryScenario foreign key(Username) references Users(Username) on delete cascade
)
```

I fill this table with data and i want to show this table in Excel 2007.
how can i do it using c#?
Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to export DataTable to Excel in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207869/how-to-export-datatable-to-excel-in-c-sharp)

Comment: the visual studio can't find this: 
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Comment: use add reference , like this : http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WindowsPhone/2011.2/CLR4.0/html/images/Getting_Started_Adding_Assembly_to_Visual_Studio_Project_03.png

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void insertBTN(object sender, EventArgs e)
{string conString = @"Data Source =XXXX; Initial Catalog=XXXX;     Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXXX; Password=XXXX";SqlConnection sqlCon     = new SqlConnection(conString);
sqlCon.Open();

 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from InjuryScenario", sqlCon);
 System.Data.DataTable dtMainSQLData = new System.Data.DataTable();
 da.Fill(dtMainSQLData);
 DataColumnCollection dcCollection = dtMainSQLData.Columns;
    // Export Data into EXCEL Sheet
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass ExcelApp = new                                            
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
    ExcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
    // ExcelApp.Cells.CopyFromRecordset(objRS);
    for (int i = 1; i < dtMainSQLData.Rows.Count + 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < dtMainSQLData.Columns.Count + 1; j++)
        {
            if (i == 1)
            {
                ExcelApp.Cells[i, j] = dcCollection[j - 1].ToString();
            }
            else
                ExcelApp.Cells[i, j] = dtMainSQLData.Rows[i - 2][j - 1].ToString();
        }
    }
    ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs("C:\\Users\\Mor Shivek\\Desktop\\test.xls");
    ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;
    ExcelApp.Quit();}
```

Comment: i succeed! thank you! do you know how can i export few tables (not just one) to number of sheets? (each table in separate sheet) i copy my code above

Answer (score 1):

> This is hundred percent working for VS-2013 Premium for C#. just copy
>   and paste the code That's it. Its working for SQL Server database You
>   can save the data into **xls, xlsx, or csv** and can use that same csv
>   for parameterization. you need to install following packages to make
>   it work.
>
> using System.Data.SqlClient
>   using Excel=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
>   using SQL = System.Data

///***Copy from here////

```
        SqlConnection cnn;
        string connectionstring = null;
        string sql = null;
        string data = null;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;



        ////*** Preparing excel Application

        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        ///*** Opening Excel application

        xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"Fullpath\Book1.csv");
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)(xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet);


        ////*** It will always remove the prvious result from the CSV file so that we can get always the updated data
        xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Select();
        xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Delete(Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
        //xlWorkBook.Save();

        /////***Opening SQL Database using Windows Authentication

        connectionstring = "Integrated Security = SSPI;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName; Data Source=ServerName;";
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
        cnn.Open();

        ////** Write your Sql Query here
        sql = "SELECT  TOP 10 [FirstName],[MiddleName],[LastName],[Email],[AltEmail],[AuthorizedUserName] From Tablename";

        ///*** Preparing to retrieve value from the database
        SQL.DataTable dtable = new SQL.DataTable();

        SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
        SQL.DataSet ds = new SQL.DataSet();
        dscmd.Fill(dtable);

        ////*** Generating the column Names here

        string[] colNames = new string[dtable.Columns.Count];

        int col = 0;

        foreach (SQL.DataColumn dc in dtable.Columns)
            colNames[col++] = dc.ColumnName;

        char lastColumn = (char)(65 + dtable.Columns.Count - 1);

        xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", lastColumn + "1").Value2 = colNames;
        xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", lastColumn + "1").Font.Bold = true;
        xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", lastColumn + "1").VerticalAlignment
                    = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;

        /////*** Inserting the Column and Values into Excel file



        for (i = 0 ; i <= dtable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j <= dtable.Columns.Count-1; j++)
                  {
                          data = dtable.Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                          xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = data;

                }
            }


        ///**Saving the csv file without notification.
            xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
            xlWorkBook.Save();


        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);

}



    private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code it's working.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection cnn;
            string connectionstring = null;
            string sql = null;
            string data = null;
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;

            Excel.Application xlApp;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;


            xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            connectionstring ="Data Source=IN-WTS-SAM;Initial Catalog=MSNETDB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";
            cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            cnn.Open();
            sql = "SELECT * FROM Emp";
            SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dscmd.Fill(ds);

            for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    data = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = data;
                }
            }


            xlWorkBook.SaveAs("informations.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();

            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlApp);


            MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file D:\\Sam-informations.xls");
        }

        private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }

        }
    }
```

Try this if it works for you.

Comment: do you know how can i do this dynamically?  if i want to work on server with several computers: ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs("C:\\Users\\Mor Shivek\\Desktop\\test.xls"); @KrunalPatil

Comment: This codes work for me  but I want to export sql table to excel with column name. Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Export sql table to excel with column name

```
for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; i++)
{
    data = ds.Tables[0].Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, i + 1] = data;
}
```