# How to convert .json file to excel in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to convert .json file to excel . iam not able to find the solution anywhere for these issue using c# language .
  Could any one help me out with these along with exact solution.

Comment: First deserialize your json using a library(JSON.NET) and then iterate your data and create the excel rows.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186(v=vs.80).aspx

    If you have any problems post the code here and we will help

Comment: @GeorgeVovos Using interop is problematic (requires Office installed and can't be used on webpages due to licensing), good alternative is OpenXML or its wrapper - [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/).

Comment: PTwr is right.When you do it, don't use interop.I also had trouble with it before

Comment: Thanks a lot . i will try these procedure as u all said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with the help of [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/), check below code for complete answer.

1. Create And write Json Data to Excel

   ```
               using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(file))
               {
                   string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                   var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);

                   List<JsonData> dataList = GetDataList(obj);

                   var fileName = file.Split('\\').Last().Split('.')[0].Trim().ToString();

                   using (ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage())
                   {
                       excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(fileName);

                       var headerRow = new List<string[]>()
                           {
                                   new string[] { "Key", "Value"}
                               };

                       string headerRange = "A1:" + Char.ConvertFromUtf32(headerRow[0].Length + 64) + "1";

                       var worksheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets[fileName];

                       worksheet.Cells[headerRange].LoadFromArrays(headerRow);

                       worksheet.Cells[2, 1].LoadFromCollection(dataList);

                       FileInfo excelFile = new FileInfo($"D:\\JsonFilesToExcel\\{folder}\\{fileName}.xlsx");
                       excel.SaveAs(excelFile);
                   }

               }
   ```
2. Create C# Object from Reading Json Key Value pairs

   ```
   public static List<JsonData> GetDataList(JObject obj)
   {
       var listResult = new List<JsonData>();

       foreach (JProperty item in (JToken)obj)
       {
           listResult.Add(new JsonData { Key = item.Name, Value = item.Value.ToString() });
       }
       return listResult;
   }
   ```

Comment: That's a paid plugin that costs around 379 dollars a year.

Answer (score 14):

Here is another partial solution, that doesn't require making a json definition, as long as the json is in a table format.

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (typeof(DataTable)));
```

From here, you can use any of the numerous datatable -> excel solutions available on the internet.

Many are posted here: 
[How to export DataTable to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207869/how-to-export-datatable-to-excel-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the data and what you want to achieve on the Excel side. I would tackle this with Json.NET and output to a CSV file, which may be opened in Excel.

Consider the following JSON... a simple array

```
[{
    "foo": "bar"
}]
```

With Json.NET we can do the following to get it into C#

```
var jsonData = "[{ \"foo\": \"bar\" }]";

var jsonDefinition = new object[]
{
    new {foo = ""}
};

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(jsonData, jsonDefinition);
```

We can then loop through the structure, outputting to a CSV file.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (dynamic o in result)
{
    sb.AppendLine(o.foo);
}
File.WriteAllText(@"c:\code\test.csv", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Hi Krisc,  In " sb.AppendLine(o.foo); " im getting an error  " The best overloaded method match for 'System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendLine(string)' has some invalid arguments " could you check once what is issue in these. Thanks

Comment: You'll have to paste your code somewhere as it's compiling for me :( Sorry!

Comment: Sounds like you just need to cast the dynamic into a string before adding it to the reader.

Answer (score 2):

I used ExcelMapper. This app is great because I just have to send it a C# list and ExcelMapper converts it to Excel. Wow!! It is available via Nuget Manager.

```
ExcelMapper em = new ExcelMapper();

em.Save(stExportFileFullPath, items, "Totals", true); 
/*
items is a list composed of the below class and fields.

public class CarrierRevenueLOBReport
{  
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }       
    public string Carrier { get; set; }
    public string LOBName { get; set; }
    public string NewOrRenewal { get; set; }
    public double SumPremium { get; set; }
    public double SumCommision { get; set; }
 }    
*/
```