# Export Formatted DataGridView To Excel

Tags: c#

I have a DataGridView which has a few rows in Red Color, Blue Color etc. I need to export DataGridView with this exact formatting to an excel sheet, My code is written below but is not working please help me.

SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();

```
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string stOutput = "";
            // Export titles:
            string sHeaders = "";

            for (int j = 0; j < dgvImportData.Columns.Count; j++)
                sHeaders = sHeaders.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dgvImportData.Columns[j].HeaderText) + "\t";

            stOutput += sHeaders + "\r\n";
            // Export data.
            if (Status == 1)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dgvImportData.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(dgvImportData.Rows[i].Cells["Status"].Value) == Status)
                    {
                        string stLine = "";
                        for (int j = 0; j < dgvImportData.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                            stLine = stLine.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dgvImportData.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value) + "\t";
                        stOutput += stLine + "\r\n";
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dgvImportData.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(dgvImportData.Rows[i].Cells["Status"].Value) == Status)
                    {
                        string stLine = "";
                        for (int j = 0; j < dgvImportData.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                            stLine = stLine.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dgvImportData.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value) + "\t";
                        stOutput += stLine + "\r\n";
                    }
                }
            }
            Encoding utf16 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1254);
            byte[] output = utf16.GetBytes(stOutput);
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(sfd.FileName, FileMode.Create);
            BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
            bw.Write(output, 0, output.Length); //write the encoded file
            bw.Flush();
            bw.Close();
            fs.Close();
```

Comment: Post some code of things that you already have? Can you guess at how to do it? Even if it's an estimated approach and the code doesn't compile you will still show that you put effort into trying to find a solution. It will also help us help you better.

Comment: I'd go for exporting your data to excel via [OpenXml](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/). But I don't think there's a standard way to format your excel sheet like your DataGridView.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to export DataTable to Excel in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207869/how-to-export-datatable-to-excel-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Add Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll to your project.

Add the following using statement:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Now add the following function to convert integer to Excel Column letter:

```
private string GetExcelColumnName(int columnNumber)
{
    int dividend = columnNumber;
    string columnName = String.Empty;
    int modulo;

    while (dividend > 0)
    {
        modulo = (dividend - 1) % 26;
        columnName = Convert.ToChar(65 + modulo).ToString() + columnName;
        dividend = (int)((dividend - modulo) / 26);
    }

    return columnName;
}
```

Then add the following function to proceed to the export

```
private void ExportToExcel(DataGridView dv)
{
    Excel.Application xlApp;

    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    xlApp.Visible = true;
    xlApp.AskToUpdateLinks = false;
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

    Excel.Workbook wb = (Excel.Workbook)xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
    Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets.Add();

    int rowstartindex = 1;

    //Create headers
    for (int i = 0; i < dv.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        Excel.Range CellHeadersRange = ws.get_Range(GetExcelColumnName(i+1) + rowstartindex.ToString(), GetExcelColumnName(i+1) + rowstartindex.ToString());
        CellHeadersRange.Value = dv.Columns[i].HeaderText;

    }

    //Write data
    for (int i = 0; i < dv.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dv.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            Excel.Range CellDataRange = ws.get_Range(GetExcelColumnName(j+1) + (i+rowstartindex+1).ToString());
            CellDataRange.Value = dv[j, i].Value;

            //Verify that backgroundcolor of datagrid is not RGB(0,0,0,0) and in that case apply datagridviewcell color to excel range
            if(!dv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor.IsEmpty)
                CellDataRange.Interior.Color = dv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor;

            //Verify that font style exist before checking for bold and in that case apply datagridviewcell font.bold property to excel range
            if(dv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.Font != null)
                CellDataRange.Font.Bold = dv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.Font.Bold;
        }
    }

    wb = null;
    ws = null;
    xlApp = null;

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

}
```

Once you understand the logic here, it's then easy to apply more style/formatting of your datagridview to the excel range.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working" where does your code crash, and which exception is thrown ?