# Convert DataTable to object[,]

Tags: c#, arrays, datatables

How convert DataTable to Array?

Source my converter from DataTable to object[,]

```
        uint rows = (uint)table.Rows.Count; 
        uint columns = (uint)table.Columns.Count;

        var data = new object[rows, columns];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (System.Data.DataRowView drv in table.DefaultView)
        {
            System.Data.DataRow ViewRow = drv.Row;
            data[i] = drv.Row.ItemArray.Clone() as object[];// Wrong number of indices inside []; expected 2    

            i++;
        }
```

Comment: You may want to try to specify the size of the cloned array `... as object[dr.Row.ItemArray.Length] // or something like this` or clone it item per item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
uint rows = (uint)table.Rows.Count; 
uint columns = (uint)table.Columns.Count;

var data = new object[rows, columns];
int i = 0;
foreach (System.Data.DataRowView drv in table.DefaultView)
{
    for( int x = 0; x<columns; x++)
{
    System.Data.DataRow ViewRow = drv.Row;
    data[i, x] = drv[x];

    i++;
}
}
```

Comment: Is that the only way? I have a very large table.

Comment: Well there are many ways.. question is what do you really want to do with this data?

Comment: I want fast to write from table to Excel,    worksheet.Range[startCell, endCell].Value2 = data;

Comment: Then this way is quite alright.  You can also check out the answers [in this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207869/how-to-export-datatable-to-excel-in-c-sharp)