# Excel Tool to compare two Excel Sheets

Tags: c#, .net, excel, comparison

This is my current code. Open to receive any comments to improve the memory optimization.

When I am taking a sample of 1000000 * 8 with 1000000*8 data its resulting into out of memory exception. Would love to have advice on optimizing memory usage.

Compare The two tables in a data set named "Before" and "After" and fill all result tables.

```
private bool CompareAndFillResultTable(DataSet ds)
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch(); stopWatch.Start();
        System.Data.DataTable dt_copy;
        dt_copy = new System.Data.DataTable();
        dt_copy = ds.Tables["Before"].Copy();
        dt_copy.TableName = "BeforeBackup";
        ds.Tables.Add(dt_copy);
        dt_copy = new System.Data.DataTable();
        dt_copy = ds.Tables["After"].Copy();
        dt_copy.TableName = "AfterBackup";
        ds.Tables.Add(dt_copy);
        dt_copy = new System.Data.DataTable();
        dt_copy = ds.Tables["Before"].Clone();
        dt_copy.TableName = "BeforeSingular";
        ds.Tables.Add(dt_copy);
        dt_copy = new System.Data.DataTable();
        dt_copy = ds.Tables["Before"].Clone();
        dt_copy.TableName = "AfterSingular";
        ds.Tables.Add(dt_copy);
        dt_copy = new System.Data.DataTable();
        dt_copy = ds.Tables["Before"].Clone();
        dt_copy.TableName = "Duplicates";
        ds.Tables.Add(dt_copy);
        dt_copy = new System.Data.DataTable();
        dt_copy = ds.Tables["Before"].Clone();
        dt_copy.TableName = "Mismatch";
        ds.Tables.Add(dt_copy);

        foreach (System.Data.DataTable table in ds.Tables)
        {
            table.Columns.Add("Source_Label");
        }

        //Remove identical from before, then after
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables["Before"].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string BeforeCompareKeyVal = ds.Tables["Before"].Rows[i][Inputs.SortColumn].ToString();
            if (ds.Tables["After"].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < ds.Tables["After"].Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    string AfterCompareKeyVal = ds.Tables["After"].Rows[j][Inputs.SortColumn].ToString();

                    if (ds.Tables["Before"].Rows[i].ItemArray.SequenceEqual(ds.Tables["After"].Rows[j].ItemArray))
                    {
                        //copy Aftter row to duplicate Table and Remove row from After
                        DataRow rw = ds.Tables["After"].Rows[j];
                        rw[ds.Tables["After"].Columns.Count - 1] = "NA";
                        ds.Tables["Duplicates"].ImportRow(rw);
                        ds.Tables["After"].Rows.RemoveAt(j);
                        j--;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (Int64.Parse(BeforeCompareKeyVal) > Int64.Parse(AfterCompareKeyVal))// Review - 7
                    {
                        if (true)//all dup after + a before - set logic
                        {
                            //Copy After row to AfterSingular Table and Remove row from After
                            DataRow rw = ds.Tables["After"].Rows[j];
                            rw[ds.Tables["After"].Columns.Count - 1] = "After";
                            ds.Tables["AfterSingular"].ImportRow(rw);
                            ds.Tables["After"].Rows.RemoveAt(j);
                            j--;
                            if (ds.Tables["After"].Rows.Count == 0)
                            {
                                rw = ds.Tables["Before"].Rows[i];
                                rw[ds.Tables["Before"].Columns.Count - 1] = "Before";
                                ds.Tables["BeforeSingular"].ImportRow(rw);
                            }
                            continue;
                        }

                    }
                    if (Int64.Parse(BeforeCompareKeyVal) < Int64.Parse(AfterCompareKeyVal))// Review - 7
                    {
                        if (true)//all dup after and a before set logic
                        {
                            //Copy Before row to BeforeSingular Table
                            DataRow rw = ds.Tables["Before"].Rows[i];
                            rw[ds.Tables["Before"].Columns.Count - 1] = "Before";
                            ds.Tables["BeforeSingular"].ImportRow(rw);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (Int64.Parse(BeforeCompareKeyVal) == Int64.Parse(AfterCompareKeyVal))// Review - 7
                    {
                        //Copy Before, After row to Mismatch Table and Remove row from After
                        if (true)//all dup after and a before set logic
                        {
                            DataRow rwB = ds.Tables["Before"].Rows[i];
                            rwB[ds.Tables["Before"].Columns.Count - 1] = "Before";
                            DataRow rwA = ds.Tables["After"].Rows[j];
                            rwA[ds.Tables["After"].Columns.Count - 1] = "After";
                            ds.Tables["Mismatch"].ImportRow(rwB);
                            ds.Tables["Mismatch"].ImportRow(rwA);
                            ds.Tables["After"].Rows.RemoveAt(j);
                            j--;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                DataRow rw = ds.Tables["Before"].Rows[i];
                rw[ds.Tables["Before"].Columns.Count - 1] = "Before";
                ds.Tables["BeforeSingular"].ImportRow(rw);
                continue;
            }
        }
        //Add remaining after table rows to AfterSingular table
        ds.Tables["AfterSingular"].Merge(ds.Tables["After"]);

        //ds.Tables["AfterSingular"].Columns.Add("Source_Label", System.Type.GetType("System.String"), "After_Singular");
        //ds.Tables["BeforeSingular"].Columns.Add("Source_Label", System.Type.GetType("System.String"), "Before_Singular");

        //foreach (System.Data.DataTable table in ds.Tables)
        //{
        //    DataRow colNames = table.NewRow();
        //    //foreach (var col in table.Columns)
        //    //{

        //    //}                
        //    for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
        //        colNames[i] = table.Columns[i].ColumnName;
        //    table.Rows.InsertAt(colNames, 0);
        //}

        foreach (System.Data.DataTable table in ds.Tables)
        {
            table.Columns.Remove(Inputs.SortColumn);
            table.AcceptChanges();
        }

        stopWatch.Stop(); lbAlert.Text = lbAlert.Text + "\n\n" + "Total Comparison time for B: " + Inputs.RowNoBeforeTable + " x " + Inputs.ColumnNoBeforeTable + " A: " + Inputs.RowNoAfterTable + " x " + Inputs.ColumnNoAfterTable + " is " + stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms, " + stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000 + " s";
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: [Excel Interop - Efficiency and performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356371/excel-interop-efficiency-and-performance) - Read and Write data to the worksheet in one operation by using a `Object[,]` - see here to convert your DataTable to an Object Array http://stackoverflow.com/a/30397080/495455.

Comment: Thank you for the references Jeremy.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use a VBA script to do this kind of thing?

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim varSheetA As Variant
    Dim varSheetB As Variant
    Dim strRangeToCheck As String
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long

    strRangeToCheck = "A1:IV65536"
    ' If you know the data will only be in a smaller range, reduce the size of the ranges above.
    Debug.Print Now
    varSheetA = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(strRangeToCheck)
    varSheetB = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(strRangeToCheck) ' or whatever your other sheet is.
    Debug.Print Now

    For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
        For iCol = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2)
            If varSheetA(iRow, iCol) = varSheetB(iRow, iCol) Then
                ' Cells are identical.
                ' Do nothing.
            Else
                ' Cells are different.
                ' Code goes here for whatever it is you want to do.
                    Cells(iRow, iCol).Select
                    With Selection.Interior
                        .Pattern = xlSolid
                        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                        .Color = 49407
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                    End With

            End If
        Next iCol
    Next iRow

End Sub
```