# Export huge data table to excel very fast

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

I need to export a huge data table consisting 100 columns and 1000 I am using .Net 4.5 as framework and C# as programming language I need a solution where this data table can be exported into Excel very quickly.

Comment: what have you done so far? and how slow is it??? how much faster would you like it to be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to export DataTable to Excel in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207869/how-to-export-datatable-to-excel-in-c-sharp)

Comment: How about you export it into a CSV file? Excel is good for viewing and processing those files and exporting to CSV is much faster.

Comment: Have you considered [Quantum Computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing) :) *Large-scale quantum computers will be able to solve certain problems much more quickly than any classical computers that use even the best currently known algorithms*

Comment: Maybe you can take a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/659666/Export-very-large-data-to-Excel-file)

Comment: Thanks DanielV your suggestion works for me.