# How to export datatable to excel in c# windows application

Tags: c#, mysql, excel

I found some code through googling that allows me to export a data table to excel file. i successfully export the file from database table and save it in my document 
My coding is:

```
  using System;
  using System.Data.OleDb;
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
  using System.Data;

namespace ImportFile

{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    String connection = "SERVER=******;"DATABASE=dbd;"UID=root;"PASSWORD=pws;"Convert Zero Datetime = True";
 private void BExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dat = DateTime.Now;
        int time = dat.Hour;
        int time1 = dat.Minute;
        int time2 = dat.Second;
        int month = dat.Month;
        int day = dat.Day;
        MySqlConnection connection1 = new MySqlConnection(connection);
        connection1.Open();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand ("SELECT * FROM TABLE_Name",connection1);     
        MySqlDataAdapter dataadpter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable datatable = new DataTable("TABLE_NAME");
        dataadpter.Fill(datatable);
        datatable.WriteXml("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\agent.xlsx" + time + " - " + time1 + " - " + time2 + " - " + day + " - " + month + "");
        MessageBox.Show("export data");

      }
     }
   }
```

my problem is that when i download file(click import button)its not download an **excel file** its just an **normal file**.

how i download it as **excel file** . if any one know this.... **help me**

Comment: Did you debug your code and see what happens exactly? I mean, you sure your select statement returns data? By the way, you are aware that you try to write an xlsx file something like `\\agent.xlsx12-4-3...` right? Are you try to put these numbers in your file name instead?

Comment: The easiest way to get such data (basic row/column data from a table) into Excel is to create a simple `csv` file. Unless you have diagrams or formatting requirements, it's the easiest way and also works well with all other kinds ob applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is one problem:

```
datatable.WriteXml("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\agent.xlsx" + time + " - " + time1 + " - " + time2 + " - " + day + " - " + month + "");
```

You wrote `agent.xlsx`, but then added some other values at the end.

The second problem is like Lewis Hai already described [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34351040/2679160), is that you're using `WriteXml` method, which will write your data as XML.

Comment: The main problem is `DataTable.WriteXml`, not the file name.

Comment: @Albireo Oh, well. Thanks for the hint. I didn't notice he's writing Xml... Was a bit too busy with the filename... Thx

Answer (score 0):

First problem as Roman said above and `datatable.WriteXml()`  with first parameter is not string. Read more at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml(v=vs.110).aspx

Second problem as this code `datatable.WriteXml` it means that you write data of datatable as XML.

Refer this post to help you more [How to export DataTable to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207869/how-to-export-datatable-to-excel)