# C#: Insert into Excel as log file

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

Is there any specific way to create a log file for my functions. All these functions are as testcases. I am using the below code to add the data.

```
string pathfile = @"data source location";
XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook(pathfile);
IXLWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheet("Common");
worksheet.Cell("A2").Value = "1";
worksheet.Cell("B2").Value = "Test Case # 1";
worksheet.Cell("C2").Value = "1/29/2016 6:18:56 PM";
worksheet.Cell("D2").Value = "1/29/2016 6:19:56 PM";
worksheet.Cell("E2").Value = "1 minute";
workbook.Save();
```

Now I have to specify this every time in my every function. Is there any other better and good way to create excel log file?

Example of Excel Log File

```
+------+-------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------+---------------+
|  ID  | Testcases No.     |        Start Time       |         End Time          |   Total Time  |  
+------+-------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------+---------------+
|  1   | Test Case # 1     |   1/29/2016 6:18:56 PM  |   1/29/2016 6:19:56 PM    |   1 minute    |  
+------+-------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------+---------------+
|  2   | Test Case # 2     |   1/29/2016 6:20:50 PM  |   1/29/2016 6:25:50 PM    |   5 minutes   |
+------+-------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------+---------------+
```

Program uses:

1. Selenium
2. Unit test class
3. Nunit to run my application

Comment: Unless you need some of the richer functionality of Excel worksheets (formulas, etc.), just dump it to a CSV.

Answer (score 1):

As a developer you should have or should be building up a project(s) of utility classes. Routines you can live without or even a framework for your project / companies.

ie Cryptography, Email, Data Access, LOGGING

This way your company or you personally can drop in this project(s) into your project and have a wealth of functionality instantly at your disposal.

I find the use of Excel for this simple logging task to be a bit heavy

So why your not using 1 of the best i.e. Net4Logger
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial

Comment: My Project is in console application and uses Selenium and NUnit to run all my test cases. The Link you sent I think it won't help.

Comment: If you add Log4Net library reference to your project and output to a log file rather than a heavy Excel spreadsheet. Do you really need an excel file for this?

Comment: Yes I do need excel. That is the reason I posted this question.

Answer (score 0):

A nice simple way is to simply create a datatable and then export it to excel using closedxml (which you already tagged, so i assume you have the library already)

```
XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook();
DataTable dt = //insert your datasource here
workbook.Worksheets.Add(dt,"WorksheetName");
```

Reference [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207869/how-to-export-datatable-to-excel)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Takarii's suggestion.

If you store your data in a `DataTable` or `List<>` then using my free C# library, you can create a real .xlsx file using the Microsoft OpenXML libraries.

[Export to Excel](http://mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/CSharp/ExportToExcel.htm)

You just need to add one line of code, saying where your data is stored, and what you want to call the Excel file:

```
List<YourLogEntryClass> listOfLogRecords = new List<YourLogEntryClass>();

. . . 

CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(listOfLogRecords, "LogFile.xlsx");
```

P.S.  A more sensible idea might be to *not* to store the log entries in an Excel file, but to use something like [log4net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8245/A-Brief-Introduction-to-the-log-net-logging-librar) which looks after all this logging info/error strings for you...

Answer (score -2):

Is there any reason not to take that block of code, and break it out into a separate function that takes file location, id, etc. as arguments?

e.g.

```
public void LogTest(string fileLocation, int id, float minutes)
{
    // your code 
}
```

Comment: No there are no reason. Also the snippet you have added is not a question. Question is I don't want to specify the cell number '(example Cel("A2"))' in every place so I am asking is how to enter the log data without specifying Column Number in my code. And adding it as a block of code, not all rows will be populate right?

Comment: @TylerH Note, this is not an answer. You shouldn't post things that should be comments as answers.

Comment: Assuming id is always equal to test number, `Cell("A" + (id + 1))` will generate the correct row, assuming the letter part doesn't change.

Comment: @Takarii I currently don't have enough reputation to add comments

Comment: @TylerH Then you need to wait until you do. Not trying to be a pain, but posting answers that aren't answers can prevent other people from reviewing a question and potentially giving an actual answer.