# How to export data from some columns from Gridcontrol to Excel file?

Tags: c#, excel, wpf

I have a `WPF` project that used `Gridcontrol`. There are 6 columns, I don't know how to export 1st,2nd,3rd column to an `excel` file? I have searched many documents but they don't helpful.

Comment: If you want to export columns of data then an itemscontrol of some sort would probably be a better starting point. You could then have a bound collection of data ( rather than a bunch of controls ) to iterate.  Working with the underlying data and binding that to or templating that into controls is the way to work with WPF.

Comment: Sound good. I'm try follow your idea. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DevExress GridControl and you need to prevent certain columns from being printed or exported, set the [GridColumn.AllowPrinting](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.BaseColumn.AllowPrinting.property) property to false.

Comment: But I want two `exportings` combine in this `Gridcontrol`. One is `columns` selected and one is another.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to get info from a DataTable:

```
var lines = new List<string>();

string[] columnNames = dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                              Select(column => column.ColumnName).
                              ToArray();

var header = string.Join(",", columnNames);
lines.Add(header);

var valueLines = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
               .Select(row => string.Join(",", row.ItemArray));            
lines.AddRange(valueLines);

File.WriteAllLines("excel.csv",lines);
```

Code taken from : [How to export DataTable to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207869/how-to-export-datatable-to-excel)

So the basic idea is this: iterate over your data bound collection and get the needed info. When done, add all the created lines to a .csv file.

This may be a solution, or maybe not, I am not aware of your constraints regarding the result file format.

Comment: Sorry, but it  didn't work because you are saying about `Datagridview` but I'm `Gridcontrol`. They have some different `properties`.