# delegate on get accessor throws incompatible type error

Tags: vb.net, delegates

I have been researching this for a while, but cant seem to make it work...

have a large sql table (many columns,rows) I must get values for into excel, I am using LINQ to SQL to get each row and using Reflection to iterate each column by name and write it to appropriate excel column. having seen that reflection is slow, I attempted to assign delegates to each property and map it (via dictionary) to the column name to avoid the overhead.

The Question:
In VB.NET when I try assigning a delegate to the GetMethod of the property (say an integer) like this:

```
Dim prop  = GetType(TestSQLClass).GetProperty("SomeColumn")
Dim del As [Delegate] = [Delegate].CreateDelegate(GetType(Func(Of Integer)), prop.GetMethod)
```

I receive this error:

> Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security
>   transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.

What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks!! was a life saver! i was getting stuck trying to pass the method parameter type as the delgate type, so if it was a Int32 property, i was creating the delegate with CreateDelegate(GetType(Func(Of Int32)), which works for regular methods, but not for the GetMethod of properties. the trick was to pass the class type, like this CreateDelegate(GetType(Func(Of Class,Int32))

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question. I thought it would be good to have an anwere and found one in C#. Please see the attributions at the bottom of the Module. I liked the idea of a DataType Extension. It even shows up in intellisense. Approximately 1500 records with 10 columns, mostly text, finishes in 3 seconds.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Module DataTableToExcel
    ' Export DataTable into an excel file with field names in the header line
    ' - Save excel file without ever making it visible if filepath Is given
    ' - Don't save excel file, just make it visible if no filepath is given
    Private excelApp As Excel.Application
    Private workSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    <Extension>
    Public Sub ExportToExcel(tbl As DataTable, excelFilePath As String)
        Dim sw As New Stopwatch
        sw.Start()
        Try
            If IsNothing(tbl) OrElse tbl.Columns.Count = 0 Then
                Throw New Exception("ExportToExcel: Null or empty input table!")
            End If
            ' load excel, And create a New workbook
            excelApp = New Excel.Application()
            excelApp.Workbooks.Add()
            ' single worksheet
            workSheet = CType(excelApp.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet)
            ' column headings
            For i = 0 To tbl.Columns.Count - 1
                workSheet.Cells(1, i + 1) = tbl.Columns(i).ColumnName
            Next
            Dim CellArray(tbl.Rows.Count - 1, tbl.Columns.Count - 1) As Object
            'rows
            For i = 0 To tbl.Rows.Count - 1
                'to do: Format DateTime values before printing
                For j = 0 To tbl.Columns.Count - 1
                    CellArray(i, j) = tbl.Rows(i)(j)
                Next
            Next
            workSheet.Range((workSheet.Cells(2, 1)), (workSheet.Cells(tbl.Rows.Count + 1, tbl.Columns.Count))).Value = CellArray
            ' check file path
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(excelFilePath) Then
                Try
                    excelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
                    workSheet.SaveAs(excelFilePath)
                    MessageBox.Show("Excel file saved!")
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Throw New Exception("ExportToExcel: Excel file could not be saved! Check filepath." & ex.Message)
                End Try
            Else  ' no file path Is given
                excelApp.Visible = True
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception("ExportToExcel:" & ex.Message)
        Finally
            excelApp.Workbooks.Close()
            excelApp.Quit()
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workSheet)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp.Workbooks)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp)
        End Try
        sw.Stop()
        Debug.Print(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString)
    End Sub
    'contributed by tuncalik; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207869/how-to-export-datatable-to-excel
    'speed improvement by Tomasz Wiśniewski
    'Releasing objects provided by  GrammatonCleric
End Module

Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class TestDataTableToExcel
    Private dt As New DataTable
    Private Sub btnCreateExcelFile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreateExcelFile.Click
        dt.ExportToExcel("Coffee.xlsx")
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCreateDataTable_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreateDataTable.Click
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.CoffeeConnectionString)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * From Coffees;", cn)
                cn.Open()
                Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    dt.Load(dr)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: oh sorry, forgot to mention, im trying to do this in Linq to SQL. its an auto-generated class containing each column from the table. im attempting to assign a delegate to the get accessor of each property in the class to avoid reflection's GetProperty()

Comment: Too bad. Linq is on top of ADO.net so it must be a bit slower. With a datareader and datatable you get headers and all the data for the excel file.