# c# Arabic Characters are not recognized when exporting datatable to Excel

Tags: c#, excel, datatable

I am trying to export from stored procedure into excel but char Arabic not recognized 
so here the code which i used on my button

```
try
{
       // Bind table data to Stream Writer to export data to respective folder
       StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(@"C:\\AllValidateReturn.xls");
       // Write Columns to excel file
       for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Columns.Count; i++)
       {
           wr.Write(datatable.Columns[i].ToString().ToUpper() + "\t");
       }
       wr.WriteLine();
       //write rows to excel file
       for (int i = 0; i < (datatable.Rows.Count); i++)
       {
            for (int j = 0; j < datatable.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                 if (datatable.Rows[i][j] != null)
                 {
                    wr.Write(Convert.ToString(datatable.Rows[i][j]) + "\t");
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    wr.Write("\t");
                 }
            }
            wr.WriteLine();
       }
       wr.Close();
       const string message = "Export Done to  C:\\AllValidateReturn.xls file";
       const string caption = "Exprot Total Counting";
       var result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption,
       MessageBoxButtons.OK,
       MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

could you please help me to solve this problem

Comment: What does *"not recognised"* mean? Where is your SQL in relation to this?

Comment: Make sure to set the encoding on your StreamWriter: [StreamWriter(System.IO.Stream stream, System.Text.Encoding encoding)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Text_Encoding_)

Comment: Please attach an example output file (a **real one**) so we can download and have a look?

Comment: Why are you saving a tab delimited file with the extension of `xls`? `xls` is a quite specific binary format. I mean it might _work_ (since Excel is very tolerant), but it is _weird._

Comment: I guess you need to set the encoding of the 'xls' file you are creating (BTW, you are creating a TAB separated CSV file there, not a 'xls' file.)

Comment: Which encoding are you using?

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/8214534/34092 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass getcoding type to streamwriter and reader as below

```
StreamWriter(@"C:\\AllValidateReturn.xls", true, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Arabic"))
```

Comment: still same but when i used this
 StreamWriter(@"C:\\AllValidateReturn.xls",true, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)

word appear fine
but show me table all as one column