# How to export data to already existing excel sheet in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I know how to create a new excel and export data into it. But how can I export data to an already existing excel which have some formats and data validation?

Comment: Show us your export code.

Comment: my export code is referred from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12533878/19449170 but it only exports data as it is to new excel.

Comment: @angelica Did you check my answer? Please, if it answers your question, mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to NuGet library [ClosedXML](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML/) .

I used it in the past and it's really straightforward.

Install the package in your solution: from VS: Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution. Alteratively, run this command from Package Manager Console: *Install-Package ClosedXML -Version 0.96.0*

In order to open and edit an existing file, use the following code:

```
string filePath = @"C:\path\to\file.xlsx";
IXLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook(filePath);
IXLWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheet(1); // Indexing from 1
worksheet.Range("A1").Value = 10;
worksheet.Range("A2").Value = 15;
worksheet.Range("A3").Value = 20;
worksheet.Range("A4").Value = 30;
workbook.Save(); // Remember to call Save method to save changes.
```

Please note: for some (probably good?) reason, sheets indexing starts from 1 instead of 0.

Remember to add the using statement: `using ClosedXML.Excel;`.

That's all! Feel free to comment / vote if you need clarifications.