# Faster way to access Range using Excel.Interop

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

There are two ways I know-

```
_xlWorksheet.Range[_xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 1], _xlWorksheet.Cells[10, 10]].Value2 = myarray.ToArray();
```

**OR**

```
_xlWorksheet.Range["A1", "J10"].Value2 = myarray.ToArray();
```

**OR**

Is there any other faster way?

As per my understanding, when I use

```
_xlWorksheet.Range[_xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 1], _xlWorksheet.Cells[10, 10]]
```

there will be three calls to interop.
But, in case of

```
_xlWorksheet.Range["A1", "J10"]
```

there will be only one call.

I am not sure which one works faster.

Comment: This has been asked numerous times!!

Comment: could not find straightforward answer. Hence, posted again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel Interop - Efficiency and performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356371/excel-interop-efficiency-and-performance)

Comment: See the duplicate...

Comment: As far as I understand your question there is no "FAST" way when choosing `.Range[_xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 1], _xlWorksheet.Cells[10, 10]]` or `Range["A1", "J10"]` They are the same.

Comment: As per my understanding, when I use _xlWorksheet.Range[_xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 1], _xlWorksheet.Cells[10, 10]] there will be three calls to interop. But, in case of _xlWorksheet.Range["A1", "J10"] there will be only one call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question there is no "FAST" way when choosing `.Range[_xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 1], _xlWorksheet.Cells[10, 10]]` or `Range["A1", "J10"]` They are the same.

In Excel, you can refer to a range, say `A1:A10`, in some of these ways

```
Debug.Print Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").Address
Debug.Print Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A10")).Address
Debug.Print Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(10, 1)).Address
```

Choosing one of the above will **NOT** determine the performance. What **WILL** determine the performance is **HOW** you *read/write* to them

Comment: As per my understanding, when I use _xlWorksheet.Range[_xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 1], _xlWorksheet.Cells[10, 10]] there will be three calls to interop. But, in case of _xlWorksheet.Range["A1", "J10"] there will be only one call.

Comment: Yes there will be but it doesn't make it slow.

Comment: running my code with multiple options. let's see what comes out :)

Comment: When you create a RCW, the RCW  for the Range object is created on the GC heap. However what’s worth noting is that the reference is created under the hood on the stack and are then discarded. They do not affect the performance in a "Major" way.

Comment: Also I would opt in for `.Range("A1:A10")` is because it is shorter and cleaner :) In the other two ways, you have to ensure that you qualify the cells inside the brackets as well :D

Comment: yes, but when I use .Range("A1:A10") I have to call a method to convert column number to column alphabet. So this is another overhead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89169/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-ankit-goel).