# Fastest method to remove Empty rows and Columns From Excel Files using Interop

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net, optimization, excel-interop

I have  a lot of excel files that contains data and it contains empty rows and empty columns.
like shown bellow

[image: Excel preview]

I am trying to remove Empty rows and columns from excel using interop.
I create a simple winform application and used the following code and it works fine.

```vb
Dim lstFiles As New List(Of String)
lstFiles.AddRange(IO.Directory.GetFiles(m_strFolderPath, "*.xls", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))

Dim m_XlApp = New Excel.Application
Dim m_xlWrkbs As Excel.Workbooks = m_XlApp.Workbooks
Dim m_xlWrkb As Excel.Workbook

For Each strFile As String In lstFiles
    m_xlWrkb = m_xlWrkbs.Open(strFile)
    Dim m_XlWrkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = m_xlWrkb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim intRow As Integer = 1

    While intRow <= m_XlWrkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If m_XlApp.WorksheetFunction.CountA(m_XlWrkSheet.Cells(intRow, 1).EntireRow) = 0 Then
            m_XlWrkSheet.Cells(intRow, 1).EntireRow.Delete(Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp)
        Else
            intRow += 1
        End If
    End While

    Dim intCol As Integer = 1
    While intCol <= m_XlWrkSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        If m_XlApp.WorksheetFunction.CountA(m_XlWrkSheet.Cells(1, intCol).EntireColumn) = 0 Then
            m_XlWrkSheet.Cells(1, intCol).EntireColumn.Delete(Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftToLeft)
        Else
            intCol += 1
        End If
    End While
Next

m_xlWrkb.Save()
m_xlWrkb.Close(SaveChanges:=True)

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(m_xlWrkb)
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(m_xlWrkbs)
m_XlApp.Quit()
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(m_XlApp)
```

But when cleaning big excel files it takes a lot of time.
Any suggestions for optimizing this code? or another way to clean this excel files faster? Is there a function that can delete empty rows in one click?

I don't have problem if answers are using C#

**EDIT:**

I uploaded a sample file [Sample File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hrqtpv9fci5cuga/Book1.xls?dl=0). But not all files have same structure.

Comment: Looks optimal to me.  A watched kettle never boils, don't wait for it.  You might consider keeping track of the files you've already processed and their last modified date so you don't fix them repeatedly.

Comment: Do you have a sample xls file we can use for testing?

Comment: I added a sample file. check out the sample file i uploaded

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found that looping through the excel worksheet can take some time if the worksheet is large. So my solution tried to avoid any looping in the worksheet. To avoid looping through the worksheet, I made a 2 dimensional object array from the cells returned from `usedRange` with:

```
Excel.Range targetCells = worksheet.UsedRange;
object[,] allValues = (object[,])targetCells.Cells.Value;
```

This is the array I loop through to get the indexes of the empty rows and columns. I make 2 int lists, one keeps the row indexes to delete the other keeps the column indexes to delete.

```
List<int> emptyRows = GetEmptyRows(allValues, totalRows, totalCols);
List<int> emptyCols = GetEmptyCols(allValues, totalRows, totalCols);
```

These lists will be sorted from high to low to simplify deleting rows from the bottom up and deleting columns from right to left. Then simply loop through each list and delete the appropriate row/col.

```
DeleteRows(emptyRows, worksheet);
DeleteCols(emptyCols, worksheet);
```

Finally after all the empty rows and columns have been deleted, I SaveAs the file to a new file name.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

Addressed the UsedRange issue such that if there are empty rows at the top of the worksheet, those rows will now be removed. Also this will remove any empty columns to the left of the starting data. This allows for the indexing to work properly even if there are empty rows or columns before the data starts. 
This was accomplished by taking the address of the first cell in UsedRange this will be an address of the form “$A$1:$D$4”. This will allow the use of an offset if the empty rows at the top and empty columns to the left are to remain and not be deleted. In this case I am simply deleting them. To get the number of rows to delete from the top can be calculated by the first “$A$4” address where the “4” is the row that the first data appears. So we need to delete the top 3 rows. The Column address is of the form “A”, “AB” or even “AAD” this required some translation and thanks to [How to convert a column number (eg. 127) into an excel column (eg. AA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181596/how-to-convert-a-column-number-eg-127-into-an-excel-column-eg-aa) I was able to determine how many columns on the left need to be deleted.

```
class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
    string originalPath = @"H:\ExcelTestFolder\Book1_Test.xls";
    Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(originalPath);
    Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
    Excel.Range usedRange = worksheet.UsedRange;

    RemoveEmptyTopRowsAndLeftCols(worksheet, usedRange);

    DeleteEmptyRowsCols(worksheet);

    string newPath = @"H:\ExcelTestFolder\Book1_Test_Removed.xls";
    workbook.SaveAs(newPath, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange);

    workbook.Close();
    excel.Quit();
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
    Console.WriteLine("Finished removing empty rows and columns - Press any key to exit");
    Console.ReadKey();
  }

  private static void DeleteEmptyRowsCols(Excel.Worksheet worksheet) {
    Excel.Range targetCells = worksheet.UsedRange;
    object[,] allValues = (object[,])targetCells.Cells.Value;
    int totalRows = targetCells.Rows.Count;
    int totalCols = targetCells.Columns.Count;

    List<int> emptyRows = GetEmptyRows(allValues, totalRows, totalCols);
    List<int> emptyCols = GetEmptyCols(allValues, totalRows, totalCols);

    // now we have a list of the empty rows and columns we need to delete
    DeleteRows(emptyRows, worksheet);
    DeleteCols(emptyCols, worksheet);
  }

  private static void DeleteRows(List<int> rowsToDelete, Excel.Worksheet worksheet) {
    // the rows are sorted high to low - so index's wont shift
    foreach (int rowIndex in rowsToDelete) {
      worksheet.Rows[rowIndex].Delete();
    }
  }

  private static void DeleteCols(List<int> colsToDelete, Excel.Worksheet worksheet) {
    // the cols are sorted high to low - so index's wont shift
    foreach (int colIndex in colsToDelete) {
      worksheet.Columns[colIndex].Delete();
    }
  }

  private static List<int> GetEmptyRows(object[,] allValues, int totalRows, int totalCols) {
    List<int> emptyRows = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 1; i < totalRows; i++) {
      if (IsRowEmpty(allValues, i, totalCols)) {
        emptyRows.Add(i);
      }
    }
    // sort the list from high to low
    return emptyRows.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList();
  }

  private static List<int> GetEmptyCols(object[,] allValues, int totalRows, int totalCols) {
    List<int> emptyCols = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 1; i < totalCols; i++) {
      if (IsColumnEmpty(allValues, i, totalRows)) {
        emptyCols.Add(i);
      }
    }
    // sort the list from high to low
    return emptyCols.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList();
  }

  private static bool IsColumnEmpty(object[,] allValues, int colIndex, int totalRows) {
    for (int i = 1; i < totalRows; i++) {
      if (allValues[i, colIndex] != null) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  private static bool IsRowEmpty(object[,] allValues, int rowIndex, int totalCols) {
    for (int i = 1; i < totalCols; i++) {
      if (allValues[rowIndex, i] != null) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  private static void RemoveEmptyTopRowsAndLeftCols(Excel.Worksheet worksheet, Excel.Range usedRange) {
    string addressString = usedRange.Address.ToString();
    int rowsToDelete = GetNumberOfTopRowsToDelete(addressString);
    DeleteTopEmptyRows(worksheet, rowsToDelete);
    int colsToDelete = GetNumberOfLeftColsToDelte(addressString);
    DeleteLeftEmptyColumns(worksheet, colsToDelete);
  }

  private static void DeleteTopEmptyRows(Excel.Worksheet worksheet, int startRow) {
    for (int i = 0; i < startRow - 1; i++) {
      worksheet.Rows[1].Delete();
    }
  }

  private static void DeleteLeftEmptyColumns(Excel.Worksheet worksheet, int colCount) {
    for (int i = 0; i < colCount - 1; i++) {
      worksheet.Columns[1].Delete();
    }
  }

  private static int GetNumberOfTopRowsToDelete(string address) {
    string[] splitArray = address.Split(':');
    string firstIndex = splitArray[0];
    splitArray = firstIndex.Split('$');
    string value = splitArray[2];
    int returnValue = -1;
    if ((int.TryParse(value, out returnValue)) && (returnValue >= 0))
      return returnValue;
    return returnValue;
  }

  private static int GetNumberOfLeftColsToDelte(string address) {
    string[] splitArray = address.Split(':');
    string firstindex = splitArray[0];
    splitArray = firstindex.Split('$');
    string value = splitArray[1];
    return ParseColHeaderToIndex(value);
  }

  private static int ParseColHeaderToIndex(string colAdress) {
    int[] digits = new int[colAdress.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < colAdress.Length; ++i) {
      digits[i] = Convert.ToInt32(colAdress[i]) - 64;
    }
    int mul = 1; int res = 0;
    for (int pos = digits.Length - 1; pos >= 0; --pos) {
      res += digits[pos] * mul;
      mul *= 26;
    }
    return res;
  }
}
```

**EDIT 2:** For testing I made a method that loops thru the the worksheet and compared it to my code that loops thru an object array. It shows a significant difference.

[image]

Method to Loop thru the worksheet and delete empty rows and columns.

```
enum RowOrCol { Row, Column };
private static void ConventionalRemoveEmptyRowsCols(Excel.Worksheet worksheet) {
  Excel.Range usedRange = worksheet.UsedRange;
  int totalRows = usedRange.Rows.Count;
  int totalCols = usedRange.Columns.Count;

  RemoveEmpty(usedRange, RowOrCol.Row);
  RemoveEmpty(usedRange, RowOrCol.Column);
}

private static void RemoveEmpty(Excel.Range usedRange, RowOrCol rowOrCol) {
  int count;
  Excel.Range curRange;
  if (rowOrCol == RowOrCol.Column)
    count = usedRange.Columns.Count;
  else
    count = usedRange.Rows.Count;

  for (int i = count; i > 0; i--) {
    bool isEmpty = true;
    if (rowOrCol == RowOrCol.Column)
      curRange = usedRange.Columns[i];
    else
      curRange = usedRange.Rows[i];

    foreach (Excel.Range cell in curRange.Cells) {
      if (cell.Value != null) {
        isEmpty = false;
        break; // we can exit this loop since the range is not empty
      }
      else {
        // Cell value is null contiue checking
      }
    } // end loop thru each cell in this range (row or column)

    if (isEmpty) {
      curRange.Delete();
    }
  }
}
```

Then a Main for testing/timing the two methods.

```
enum RowOrCol { Row, Column };

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
  string originalPath = @"H:\ExcelTestFolder\Book1_Test.xls";
  Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(originalPath);
  Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
  Excel.Range usedRange = worksheet.UsedRange;

  // Start test for looping thru each excel worksheet
  Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
  Console.WriteLine("Start stopwatch to loop thru WORKSHEET...");
  sw.Start();
  ConventionalRemoveEmptyRowsCols(worksheet);
  sw.Stop();
  Console.WriteLine("It took a total of: " + sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds + " Miliseconds to remove empty rows and columns...");

  string newPath = @"H:\ExcelTestFolder\Book1_Test_RemovedLoopThruWorksheet.xls";
  workbook.SaveAs(newPath, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange);
  workbook.Close();
  Console.WriteLine("");

  // Start test for looping thru object array
  workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(originalPath);
  worksheet = workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
  usedRange = worksheet.UsedRange;
  Console.WriteLine("Start stopwatch to loop thru object array...");
  sw = new Stopwatch();
  sw.Start();
  DeleteEmptyRowsCols(worksheet);
  sw.Stop();

  // display results from second test
  Console.WriteLine("It took a total of: " + sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds + " Miliseconds to remove empty rows and columns...");
  string newPath2 = @"H:\ExcelTestFolder\Book1_Test_RemovedLoopThruArray.xls";
  workbook.SaveAs(newPath2, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange);
  workbook.Close();
  excel.Quit();
  System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
  System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
  Console.WriteLine("");
  Console.WriteLine("Finished testing methods - Press any key to exit");
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**EDIT 3** As per OP request...
I updated and changed the code to match the OP code. With this I found some interesting results. See below.

I changed the code to match the functions you are using ie… EntireRow and CountA. The code below I found that it preforms terribly. Running some tests I found the code below was in the 800+ milliseconds execution time. However one subtle change made a huge difference.

On the line:

```
while (rowIndex <= worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
```

This is slowing things down a lot. If you create a range variable for UsedRang and not keep regrabbibg it with each iteration of the while loop will make a huge difference. So… when I change the while loop to…

```
Excel.Range usedRange = worksheet.UsedRange;
int rowIndex = 1;

while (rowIndex <= usedRange.Rows.Count)
and
while (colIndex <= usedRange.Columns.Count)
```

This performed very close to my object array solution. I did not post the results, as you can use the code below and change the while loop to grab the UsedRange with each iteration or use the variable usedRange to test this.

```
private static void RemoveEmptyRowsCols3(Excel.Worksheet worksheet) {
  //Excel.Range usedRange = worksheet.UsedRange;     // <- using this variable makes the while loop much faster 
  int rowIndex = 1;

  // delete empty rows
  //while (rowIndex <= usedRange.Rows.Count)     // <- changing this one line makes a huge difference - not grabbibg the UsedRange with each iteration...
  while (rowIndex <= worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count) {
    if (excel.WorksheetFunction.CountA(worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, 1].EntireRow) == 0) {
      worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, 1].EntireRow.Delete(Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);
    }
    else {
      rowIndex++;
    }
  }

  // delete empty columns
  int colIndex = 1;
  // while (colIndex <= usedRange.Columns.Count) // <- change here also

  while (colIndex <= worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count) {
    if (excel.WorksheetFunction.CountA(worksheet.Cells[1, colIndex].EntireColumn) == 0) {
      worksheet.Cells[1, colIndex].EntireColumn.Delete(Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftToLeft);
    }
    else {
      colIndex++;
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE by [@Hadi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7031230/hadi)**

You can alter `DeleteCols` and `DeleteRows` function to get better performance if excel contains extra blank rows and columns after the last used ones:

```
private static void DeleteRows(List<int> rowsToDelete, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet)
{
    // the rows are sorted high to low - so index's wont shift

    List<int> NonEmptyRows = Enumerable.Range(1, rowsToDelete.Max()).ToList().Except(rowsToDelete).ToList();

    if (NonEmptyRows.Max() < rowsToDelete.Max())
    {

        // there are empty rows after the last non empty row

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cell1 = worksheet.Cells[NonEmptyRows.Max() + 1,1];
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cell2 = worksheet.Cells[rowsToDelete.Max(), 1];

        //Delete all empty rows after the last used row
        worksheet.Range[cell1, cell2].EntireRow.Delete(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);


    }    //else last non empty row = worksheet.Rows.Count



    foreach (int rowIndex in rowsToDelete.Where(x => x < NonEmptyRows.Max()))
    {
        worksheet.Rows[rowIndex].Delete();
    }
}

private static void DeleteCols(List<int> colsToDelete, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet)
{
    // the cols are sorted high to low - so index's wont shift

    //Get non Empty Cols
    List<int> NonEmptyCols = Enumerable.Range(1, colsToDelete.Max()).ToList().Except(colsToDelete).ToList();

    if (NonEmptyCols.Max() < colsToDelete.Max())
    {

        // there are empty rows after the last non empty row

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cell1 = worksheet.Cells[1,NonEmptyCols.Max() + 1];
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cell2 = worksheet.Cells[1,NonEmptyCols.Max()];

        //Delete all empty rows after the last used row
        worksheet.Range[cell1, cell2].EntireColumn.Delete(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftToLeft);


    }            //else last non empty column = worksheet.Columns.Count

    foreach (int colIndex in colsToDelete.Where(x => x < NonEmptyCols.Max()))
    {
        worksheet.Columns[colIndex].Delete();
    }
}
```

*check my answer at [Get Last non empty column and row index from excel using Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43910117/get-last-non-empty-column-and-row-index-from-excel-using-interop?noredirect=1&lq=1)*

Comment: Dam this was the answer I didn't have time to complete and submit yesterday... kudos! REF http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356371/excel-interop-efficiency-and-performance Can you put a StopWatch in this and compare times? That would really garner some rep points.

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson I did not think it would make that much difference, but I think it is clear that constantly changing ranges in excel is expensive. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Thanks for your effort.. but in the loop methods you are looping over cells. it is not what i have done. I used `If m_XlApp.WorksheetFunction.CountA(m_XlWrkSheet.Cells(1, intCol).EntireColumn) = 0`

Comment: Amazing man!!! my algorithm was spending 90 sec on a file, and yours reduced time to 17 sec

Comment: i didn't marked your answer because i am giving a chance for a better optimization. if not your answer is the best. i upvoted it

Comment: This is the best answer you are going to get using Interop @H.Fadlallah - if you want faster use ClosedXML to avoid Interop altogether, which will only work on XLSX. The reason Interop is so slow is because each time you update a cell, an RPC call is marshalled to the Excel process. This is why working with Ranges is so much faster (or preferably `UsedRange` and working with an `object[,]`). This guy deserves the bounty!

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson as per OP, I added the code that closely matches the OPs original code, and found a subtle change that will make the code perform close to my solution. Thanks for every ones help.

Comment: Thank you @Hadi, I ran into that situation where there were 50,000+ supposed empty rows at the end and my code took an unacceptable amount of time to finish. I was meaning to update the answer with what you posted. Thank you for the helpful, needed and constructive edit.

Comment: @JohnG happy to help

Comment: @JohnG you answer is amazing and helped me a lot. I opened a new bounty as a reward for it. i will award it before it will ends up to give you more upvotes. :)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe something to consider:

```
Sub usedRangeDeleteRowsCols()
    Dim LastRow, LastCol, i As Long

    LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
    LastCol = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column

    For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, LastCol))) = 0 Then
            Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next

    For i = LastCol To 1 Step -1
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(LastRow, i))) = 0 Then
            Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I *think* there are two efficiencies compared to equivalent functions in the original code. Firstly, instead of using Excel's unreliable UsedRange property, we find the last value and only scan rows and columns within the genuine used range.

Secondly the worksheet count function again only works within the genuine used range - for example when searching for blank rows we only look in the range of used columns (rather than `.EntireRow`).

The `For` loops work backwards because, for example, every time a row is deleted, the row address of following data changes. Working backwards means the row addresses of "data to be worked on" doesn't change.

Comment: Same performance!! But voted up because i liked the way you thinked

Comment: Ah, thank you v much! It's a real shame it didn't speed things up. Perhaps another part of the code is causing most delay, but I'm not sure what it could be...

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion the most time consuming part could be enumerating and finding empty rows and columns.

What about:
http://www.howtogeek.com/206696/how-to-quickly-and-easily-delete-blank-rows-and-columns-in-excel-2013/

**EDIT:**

What about:

```
m_XlWrkSheet.Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
m_XlWrkSheet.Rows("1:1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireColumn.Delete
```

Tested on sample data result looks ok, performance better (tested from VBA but difference is huge).

**UPDATE:**

Tested on sample Excel with 14k rows (made from sample data) original code ~30 s, this version <1s

Comment: Nice one. but i doesn't help. because there are non empty rows containing null columns

Comment: @H.Fadlallah: Is this corrected version fullfilling your criteria?

Comment: Man this is an amazing method... but only if Empty cells are contained in a non nullable column (case of a primary key) or Row. in my case it will delete a lot of rows that conatins data

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way that I know of is to hide non-blank cells and delete the visible ones:

```
var range = m_XlWrkSheet.UsedRange;
range.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow.Hidden = true;
range.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible).Delete(XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);
range.EntireRow.Hidden = false;
```

Faster methods are to not delete anything at all, but to move (cut+paste) the non-blank areas.

The fastest Interop way (there are faster more complicated methods without opening the file) is to get all values in array, move the values in the array, and put the values back:

```
object[,] values = m_XlWrkSheet.UsedRange.Value2 as object[,];

// some code here (the values start from values[1, 1] not values[0, 0])

m_XlWrkSheet.UsedRange.Value2 = values;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could open an ADO connection to the worksheet, get a list of fields, issue an SQL statement which includes only known fields, and also exclude records with no values in the known fields.

Comment: Ado connection is not best way to work with excel because excel is not a very well structured table. You may have columns without header. Columns with mixed data types and many issues...