# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel how to get the correct last row?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am trying to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to get the row number of my excel file, which is 40424 rows.

I have tried codes below:

[image: Debug Infos]

They only returns 38304, which is not correct.
What is the correct way to get the right row number?

Comment: Try this: `int lastRow = old_sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing).Row`

Comment: I have just tried that, same return.

Comment: I have also tried: sheet.UsedRange.Row + sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, I don't know whether it's relate to my excel file, because when I use it on other files, It' correct.

Comment: Did you changed `int` to `long`?

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: You don't happen to have an old copy of the file (one which had 38304 rows) open in excel?

Comment: Check 38305-row, there may be something different

Comment: I can not see why you are not getting the correct number of rows... just guessing... are you sure you have the correct sheet? Are there other sheets in the workbook?

Comment: `book.Sheets[1]`. Is that accessing the second sheet?

Comment: If nothing works, upload your file to dropbox/G-Drive/skydrive and see if we can have a look.  Something is clearly amiss.

Comment: if you have a non nullable column you can try this workaround `app.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sheet.Cells(1, intCol).EntireColumn)`

Comment: Empty rows can cause this issue. take a look at this  [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574084/remove-empty-rows-and-columns-from-excel-files-using-interop)

Comment: Thank you all, I have found the problem, there is actualy an hiden sheet which which is 38304 rows. - -! @sgmoore

Answer (score 1):

After I try:
[image]
[Hide or show worksheets or workbooks](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Hide-or-show-worksheets-or-workbooks-69f2701a-21f5-4186-87d7-341a8cf53344)

I found there is actualy an hiden sheet. - -!

Thank you all guys, problem solved.