# How to delete empty columns in Collections

Tags: blueprism

I am working with  Excel when I copy data Excel to collections I am getting 3 more empty columns in my collection. If I use Utility-.manipulation VBO  am able to delete only one column. Any one please let me know if you have solution for this.

Thanks for your time...

Comment: What are the names of the blank columns? From the text of the question as it currently stands, it's unclear what happens when you attempt to leverage the appropriate Action in the Utility - Collection Manipulation VBO.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I am copying data Excel to collections with out headers data is having 5 columns but it is copying 8 columns. By using utility- collection Manipulation and the action delete column I can able to delete only one column, but I want to delete all empty columns in collections.

Comment: You say you can delete only one column - why not the rest?

Comment: Excatly, if you know the solution that will be helpful...

Comment: Why not just copy the same stage again and target it to a different column name you'd like to delete?

Comment:  that's not the best practice, in future if it will copy more empty columns I can't change the code again. So I want to delete all empty columns together.

Comment: sounds like your Excel file is in bad shape. If columns are totally blank, then you should be able to use currentregion instead of Usedrange in the Excel VBO

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't feed blank columns into the collection in the first place. I don't think Blue Prism has released a VBO with the exact functionality that you are looking for. If you are willing to dabble into creating your own solution using code stages in Blue Prism, you may wish to check out this post:  [Fastest method to remove Empty rows and Columns From Excel Files using Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574084/fastest-method-to-remove-empty-rows-and-columns-from-excel-files-using-interop).
Or you could create a macro in Excel to take care of the empty columns. Excel, Word, etc...macros can be run from Blue Prism processes using the standard "MS Excel VBO> Run Macro", so that's another option.