# Bulk insert from excel to sql for selective fields on the basis of cell location

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

I have a SSIS package where I have to select some values from an excel sheet and insert them into a SQL Server database table, i am doing it through Execute sql task.

These are the steps:

1. Select all records from mapping table, cell location is dynamic so keeping it in sql table (around 3000 cells are there - we have to pick value from selective fields in Excel and not all)

Example:

[image]

2. Iterate through `Foreach` on each record
3. Create a query with cell name and Sheet name

   Example: `Select * from [GenDet$F3:F3]`
4. Execute the query to get that cell's value from Excel sheet

Example:

[image]

5. Insert the values into the sql database table

[image]

It is working - but the problem is the time which it is taking. For 3000 fields, this whole process is taking 50 minutes to process one Excel file. I have to do this in less than a minute.

Please let me know the best approach to achieve this.

Thank you!

Comment: What are you doing for steps in the SSIS package? That seems important. Is this an Execute SQL task with a raw bulk insert query--and you're looping it over each field value? If you're using bulk insert on each data point individually that is most likely why it's taking 50 minutes.

Comment: Also, please use character tables vs images. No one wants to retype your work to provide you answers.

Comment: I think that writing a c# script that read the data from excel cells and group them into a list or DataTable then perform a Bulk insert once will be more performant

Comment: Have you tried saving the Excel worksheet as a .csv file containing only the fields needed? SSIS should be able to ingest that quickly. Saving the Excel file can easily be scripted in PowerShell or VBA.

Comment: Yes I am doing it as an Execute Sql Task, I am not sure how to use bulk insert because the cells' location is dynamic and can change anytime so need to take it from Mapping table for each field.

Comment: I think you should go with a c# approach since it is more performant with similar cases. You have an very good answer provided that describe the whole process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As i mentioned in the comments, I think that writing a c# script that read the data from excel cells and group them into a list or DataTable then perform a Bulk insert once will be more performant*

## C# application/script task

### Needed assemblies

First you have to import Excel Interop assembly:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

### Convert column header letter to index

Now you should define the following function that convert the excel column alphabet to index:

```
private int ParseColHeaderToIndex(string colAdress)
{
    int[] digits = new int[colAdress.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < colAdress.Length; i++)
    {
        digits[i] = Convert.ToInt32(colAdress[i]) - 64;
    }
    int mul = 1;
    int res = 0;
    for (int pos = digits.Length - 1; pos >= 0; pos--)
    {
        res += digits[pos] * mul;
        mul *= 26;
    }
    return res;
}
```

### SQL bulk insert function

The following function is to perform bulk insert operation into SQL

```
public void InsertToSQLUsingSQLBulk(System.Data.DataTable dt, string connectionstring, string Tablename)
{


    try
    {
        using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionstring, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))
        {

            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(col.ColumnName, col.ColumnName);
            }

            bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 600;
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = Tablename;
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

### Reading from excel into destination DataTable

The following function takes the excel path and the ranges DataTable as parameter and return a DataTable having the destination structure *(Id, AttributeKey, AttributeValue)*

```
public System.Data.DataTable ReadFromExcel(System.Data.DataTable dtRanges,string strPath)
{

    string num = "0123456789";

    //Declare result datatable  
    System.Data.DataTable destination = new System.Data.DataTable();
    destination.Columns.Add("Id");
    destination.Columns.Add("AttributeKey");
    destination.Columns.Add("AttributeValue");

    //Decalre Interop Objects
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application m_XlApp;
     m_XlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
     m_XlApp.Visible = false;
     m_XlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

     Workbook xlWbs = null;
     xlWbs = m_XlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                                   Type.Missing, "'", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                                   Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                                   Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
                                   Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

    xlWbs.DoNotPromptForConvert = true;
    xlWbs.CheckCompatibility = false;
    xlWbs.Application.DisplayAlerts = false;

    //Loop over worksheets
    foreach (Worksheet xlWks in xlWbs.Worksheets) {

        string Name = xlWks.Name;

        //Assing rows relevant to the current sheet

        foreach (DataRow drRow in dtRanges.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x["Sheet_Name"].ToString() == Name))
        {

            string sheet = drRow["Sheet_Name"].ToString();
            string range = drRow["Location_Value"].ToString();
            string field = drRow["Field_Name"].ToString();
            string id = drRow["Id"].ToString();
            string rangeAlpha = range.Split(':')[0];
            int rowidx = 0;
            int colidx = 0;



            foreach (char chr in num) { 
                rangeAlpha = rangeAlpha.Replace(chr, '\0');
            }

            rowidx = Int32.Parse(range.Split(':')[0].Replace(rangeAlpha, ""));
            colidx = ParseColHeaderToIndex(rangeAlpha);


            DataRow dr = destination.NewRow();

            if (xlWks.Cells[rowidx, colidx] != null && (xlWks.Cells[rowidx, colidx] as Range).Value2 != null)
            {

                dr["AttributeValue"] = (string)(xlWks.Cells[rowidx, colidx] as Range).Value2;
            }
            else
            {
                dr["AttributeValue"] = "";
            }



            dr["AttributeKey"] = drRow["Field_Name"].ToString();
            dr["Id"] = drRow["Id"].ToString();

            destination.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

    }

    xlWbs.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    m_XlApp.Quit();
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWbs);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(m_XlApp);


    return destination;

}
```

### Main program

```
public void Main(){

    //Initialize ranges table
    System.Data.DataTable ranges = new System.Data.DataTable();
    ranges.Columns.Add("Id");
    ranges.Columns.Add("Field_Name");
    ranges.Columns.Add("Location_Value");
    ranges.Columns.Add("Sheet_Name");

    //Add rows or read them from database using SQLDataAdapter


    //note that the destination table must exists in the database with identical columns of datatable

    System.Data.DataTable destination = ReadFromExcel(ranges, "C:\\1.xlsx", "dbo.destination");

    InsertToSQLUsingSQLBulk(destination, "Pass SQL Server destination connection string here");



}
```

---

## Update 1 - Improve performance

You can improve the method performance by putting all worksheet contents inside an two dimension array, then loop over array instead of looping inside the Excel worksheet.

```
Excel.Range targetCells = xlWks.UsedRange;
object[,] allValues = (object[,])targetCells.Cells.Value;

...


 if (targetCells.Cells[rowidx, colidx] != null)
 {

     dr["AttributeValue"] = (string)(targetCells.Cells[rowidx, colidx] as Range).Value2;
  }
  else
  {
     dr["AttributeValue"] = "";
  }
```

**Reference**

- [Fastest method to remove Empty rows and Columns From Excel Files using Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574084/fastest-method-to-remove-empty-rows-and-columns-from-excel-files-using-interop)

Comment: Thank you so much Hadi for such elaborated solution, I am implementing it and will let u know about the outcome.

Comment: @Faizi check my answer update, you might find it interesting

Answer (score 1):

How about considering building one select statement to run that gets all the records at once.

Based on your image, something like this:

```
select
 (Select [Field1] from [GenDet$I3:I3]) as Field1
,(Select [Field2] from [GenDet$I4:I4]) as Field2
...
```

That was horizontal and column based.

or you can go vertical with

```
 (Select [FieldName],[Field1] as Value from [GenDet$I3:I3]) as Field1
union all
 (Select [Field2],* from [GenDet$I4:I4]) as Field2
...
```

I know there are 3000 or so but you can build this with a string concatenation query rather simply.

Just a thought.

This would decrease execution time as the spreadsheet is not opening and closing on every iteration.

Comment: When using OleDb to connection to excel or access there is a limit of allowed UNION operation (i think maximum 16 UNION) so it will not work in this case

Comment: The cells location is dynamic so i cannot keep it static in queries, its a compulsion to  take location of each field from mapping table.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you build the query through string concatenation query id the mapping table

Comment: But Hadi makes a good point. I'd rather both this in c#. Read mapping table into data table. Then loop thru that inside a using statement to read from excel directly to a data flow. That's not easy to do but it's a good option.

Comment: @KeithL i tried to write an C# application check my answer and i am open for any suggestions

Comment: I just have phone access but it would be difficult to check. I use oledb for excel in c#. I never doubt your answers. You are the best  @hadi

Comment: Thanks KeithL, I have implemented it, SSIS allows upto 50 UNIONs at a time or may be it is the max size of string query. The execution time reduced from 50 mins to 14  mins .