# trying to get the last cell address based on range giving wrong value

Tags: c#, .net, excel, linq

I am trying to get the last cell address from the excel sheet for merging purposes based on starting address and range using the below code.

I have starting cell address like `X` and would like to get the end cell address using the given range. For example, starting address is `X`, and the range is 7, then the end cell address would be `AD`.

I have tried with the below approach and I am getting wrong end cell address

```
private static readonly char[] BaseChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();

private static readonly Dictionary<char, int> CharValues = BaseChars
           .Select((c, i) => new { Char = c, Index = i })
           .ToDictionary(c => c.Char, c => c.Index);

public static string IntToBase(int value)
{
    int targetBase = BaseChars.Length;
    // Determine exact number of characters to use.
    char[] buffer = new char[Math.Max(
               (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(value + 1, targetBase)), 1)];

    var i = buffer.Length;
    do
    {
        buffer[--i] = BaseChars[value % targetBase];
        value /= targetBase;
    }
    while (value > 0);

    return new string(buffer, i, buffer.Length - i);
}

public static int BaseToInt(string number)
{
    _ = number ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(number));
    char[] chrs = number.ToCharArray();
    int m = chrs.Length - 1;
    int n = BaseChars.Length, x;
    int result = 0;
    foreach (char c in chrs)
    {
        x = CharValues[c];
        result += x * (int)Math.Pow(n, m--);
    }
    return result;
}

public static string GetLastCellAddress(string number, int cellCount)
{
    int startVal = BaseToInt(number);
    return Enumerable.Range(startVal, cellCount).Select(i => IntToBase(i)).Last();
}
```

And I am using above function like as below

```
var environmentsLastCellAddress =  ExcelBuilderExtensions.GetLastCellAddress(startColumnAddress, spaceTypeLibraryByPropertiesCount);
```

The above function gives the wrong end address if I have given starting cell address like `X` and count is `7`, and I should get the end cell address as `AD` instead of I am getting address as `BD.`

Could anyone please let me know is there anything wrong with the above code? That would be very grateful to me. Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am hoping the following will work for you.

`int` to `string` reference…

[Convert an Excel column number to a column name or letter:](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/11/13/convert-excel-column-number-to-name/)

`string` to `int` reference…

[Fastest method to remove Empty rows and Columns From Excel Files using Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574084/fastest-method-to-remove-empty-rows-and-columns-from-excel-files-using-interop/40726309#40726309)

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  Console.WriteLine("Start: A + 0: " + GetAddedRange("A", 0));
  Console.WriteLine("Start: A + 1: " + GetAddedRange("A", 1));
  Console.WriteLine("Start: H + 4: " + GetAddedRange("H", 4));
  Console.WriteLine("Start: AA + 26: " + GetAddedRange("AA", 26));
  Console.WriteLine("Start: BA + 11: " + GetAddedRange("BA", 11));
  Console.WriteLine("Start: CAA + 11: " + GetAddedRange("CAA", 11));
  Console.WriteLine("Start: GAA + 11: " + GetAddedRange("GAA", 11));
  Console.WriteLine("Start: Z + 11: " + GetAddedRange("Z", 11));
  Console.WriteLine("Start: Z - 10: " + GetAddedRange("Z", -10));
  Console.ReadKey();
}

private static string ColumnIndexToColumnLetter(int colIndex) {
  int div = colIndex;
  string colLetter = String.Empty;
  int mod = 0;
  while (div > 0) {
    mod = (div - 1) % 26;
    colLetter = (char)(65 + mod) + colLetter;
    div = (int)((div - mod) / 26);
  }
  return colLetter;
}

private static int ParseColHeaderToIndex(string colAdress) {
  int[] digits = new int[colAdress.Length];
  for (int i = 0; i < colAdress.Length; ++i) {
    digits[i] = Convert.ToInt32(colAdress[i]) - 64;
  }
  int mul = 1;
  int res = 0;
  for (int pos = digits.Length - 1; pos >= 0; --pos) {
    res += digits[pos] * mul;
    mul *= 26;
  }
  return res;
}

private static string GetAddedRange(string startCol, int addedRange) {
  int startingCol = ParseColHeaderToIndex(startCol);
  return ColumnIndexToColumnLetter(startingCol + addedRange);
}
```

Also from your second to last comment… X + 7 would be AE… not AD.

Comment: Sorry, I am getting wrong address If i have given start address is like `D` and range would be 11 I should get `N`. Instead I am getting `O` as end address. The start address should include start cell address as well.

Comment: Sorry, but form my calculation D + 11 = O  ... D ... e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o ...

Comment: If i pass `AddedRange-1` it should work

Comment: So if you had any letter(s) + 1… then… it should return the same letter?

Comment: yeah, the count should start from starting address it self

Comment: Well I am sorry, but this seems rather trivial since you could easily do range-1. In addition as my last comment states, it seems odd to have A+1 returning A. A+0 should return A.

Comment: Thank you for the support :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in excel, you may also let excel do the job:

```
Private Function GetColName(ColNr As Integer) As String
Dim parts() As String
  parts = Split(Cells(1, ColNr).Address, "$")
  GetColName = parts(1)
End Function

Private Function GetColNr(ColName As String) As Long
  GetColNr = Range(ColName + "1").Column
End Function

Sub test()
  MsgBox GetColName(GetColNr("X") + 7) 'will post AE
End Sub
```

You may combine this to one function and also add error handling.