# Export to Excel got null references

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, excel

I'm using C#, WPF and Microsoft SQL Server.

When I press my `Export` button, it results in errors. The **header** is populated, but not the **data**.

I'm suspicious with my filter function.

Here's the filter function which correspond to the DataGrid.

```
private void theFilter(string FilterValue, string FilterValueYear, string FilterValueMonth) 
{
    string thisQuery = "SELECT [TransportRecord].[TransportRecordId], [Transporter].[Name] as [TransporterName], [Customer].[Name] as [CustomerName], [Destination].[Name] as [DestinationName], [FuelType].[Name] as [FuelTypeName], [TransportRecord].[SO], [TransportRecord].[Quantity],  [TransportRecord].[Price], [TransportRecord].[Date]" +
            "               FROM [TransportRecord]" +
            "               INNER JOIN [Transporter] ON [TransportRecord].[TransporterId] = [Transporter].[TransporterId]" +
            "               INNER JOIN [Customer] ON [TransportRecord].[CustomerId] = [Customer].[CustomerId]" +
            "               INNER JOIN [Destination] ON [TransportRecord].[DestinationId] = [Destination].[DestinationId]" +
            "               INNER JOIN [FuelType] ON [TransportRecord].[FuelTypeId] = [FuelType].[FuelTypeId]" +
            "               WHERE CONCAT([Transporter].[Name], [Customer].[Name], [FuelType].[Name], [Destination].[Name], [TransportRecord].[SO], [TransportRecord].[Quantity], [TransportRecord].[Price]) LIKE @FilterValue AND DATEPART(YYYY, [TransportRecord].[Date]) LIKE @FilterValueYear AND DATEPART(MM, [TransportRecord].[Date]) LIKE @FilterValueMonth AND DATEPART(DD, [TransportRecord].[Date]) BETWEEN @FilterValueStartPeriod AND @FilterValueEndPeriod ORDER BY [TransportRecord].[Date]";

    using(SqlConnection thisSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(theConnectionString))
    using(SqlCommand thisSqlCommand = new SqlCommand(thisQuery, thisSqlConnection)) 
    {
        thisSqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@FilterValue", SqlDbType.Text).Value = "%" + FilterValue + "%";
        thisSqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@FilterValueYear", SqlDbType.Text).Value = "%" + FilterValueYear + "%";
        thisSqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@FilterValueMonth", SqlDbType.Text).Value = "%" + FilterValueMonth + "%";
        thisSqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@FilterValueStartPeriod", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = theStartPeriod;
        thisSqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@FilterValueEndPeriod", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = theEndPeriod;

        using(SqlDataAdapter thisSqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(thisSqlCommand))
        using(DataTable thisDataTable = new DataTable()) 
        {
            thisSqlDataAdapter.Fill(thisDataTable);

            DataGrid_TransportRecord.ItemsSource = thisDataTable.DefaultView;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my export function:

```
private void Button_ExcelExport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    theExcelExport();
}

private void theExcelExport() 
{
    Excel.Application thisExcelApplication = new Excel.Application();
    thisExcelApplication.Visible = true;

    Excel.Workbook thisExcelWorkbook = thisExcelApplication.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);

    Excel.Worksheet thisExcelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)thisExcelWorkbook.Sheets[1];

    for(int j = 0; j < DataGrid_TransportRecord.Columns.Count; j ++) 
    {
         Excel.Range thisExcelRange = (Excel.Range)thisExcelWorksheet.Cells[1, j + 1];
         thisExcelWorksheet.Cells[1, j + 1].Font.Bold = true;
         thisExcelWorksheet.Columns[j + 1].ColumnWidth = 15;
         thisExcelRange.Value2 = DataGrid_TransportRecord.Columns[j].Header;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < DataGrid_TransportRecord.Columns.Count; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < DataGrid_TransportRecord.Items.Count; j ++) 
        {
            TextBlock thisTextBlock = DataGrid_TransportRecord.Columns[i].GetCellContent(DataGrid_TransportRecord.Items[j]) as TextBlock;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range thisExcelRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)thisExcelWorksheet.Cells[j + 2, i + 1];
            thisExcelRange.Value2 = thisTextBlock.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A pox on your house for using embedded SQL.  Just kidding ;)

Comment: Doing it cell by cell with interop is extremely slow, try this method instead where you add or extract values using an object array: https://stackoverflow.com/q/356371/495455

Comment: Could you describe what errors you get and in which place in code?

Comment: It only generates the header, but not the Data. And resulting "null references" exception.

Comment: The place is on the Export function

Comment: @JeremyThompson, how can I implement those in my code?

Comment: @LemBidi it has crystal clear instructions... you need to follow instructions. We are **NOT** here to spoon feed you... if you cant get it to work then you haven't learnt the first lesson of computer programming, *go after things like a dog after a bone*!

Comment: Yeah just copy-paste that stuff from youtube tuts.
gotta learn it as well.